# Изучение С++ после С#

Tags: c#, c++, книги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошую книгу по С++ для человека со знанием C# на хорошем уровне.

Такую, чтобы не объяснялись основы вида «что такое переменная», но при этом были описаны специфичные для С++ вещи, например, работа с указателями, заголовочными файлами и т.п.

В принципе, можно и на английском языке.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup. - сам язык.

C++ Primer Plus (5th Edition) by Steven Prata. - + лабораторный практикум.

Answer (score 2):

Герберт Шилдт "Полный справочник по С++" четвертое издание.

Answer (score 2):

Bjarne Stroustrup "Programming: Principles and Practises Using C++"
в русском варианте "Программирование. Принципы и практика использования C++"

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется самое то для вас будет вот эта книга! 
[Книга](http://www.tinlib.ru/kompyutery_i_internet/c_dlja_professionalov_tom_ii/p14.php#metkadoc2)
Она для перехода с С++ на С# но она подойдет и для вас, так как примеры кода даны на С++ и на C#.

Answer (score 0):

Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days Fifth edition
Jesse Liberty
Bradly Jones

есть и на русском языке, но там переводили люди неочень как кажется связанные с программированием. но если с английским беда, то и русский вариант можно. к тому же если вы уже умеете что-то. объяснено понятно, примеры неплохие, листинги есть после которых обязательный анализ. так за месяц-полтора будете легко в С++ стандартном ориентироватся ))

Answer (score 0):

Неплохие книги из моего "золотого архива":

Книга написана очень доступным языком:

```
"Лафоре Р. Объектно-ориентированное программирование на C++"
```

И как более заточенное под платформу. Книга хороша для тех, кто испытывает некий конфуз перед Visual Studio - грубо говоря, книга предназначена для тех, кто не знаком с интерфейсом среды разработки и хочет чтобы его научили обращаться с ней параллельно с изучением С++:

```
"Прохоренок Н.А. - Программирование на С++ в Visual Studio 2010 Express - 2010"
```