# Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++

Tags: c++, книги, c++-faq

В этом вопросе собирается литература по языку C++

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.
- Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги. (когда она будет)

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Если сомневаетесь в выборе, следуйте простым и объективным рекомендациям в конце этого ответа.

## Для начинающих

- Стефан Рэнди Дэвис - *[C++ для чайников, 7-е издание](http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1952-6.html)*
- Сиддхартха Рао - *[Освой самостоятельно C++ по одному часу в день](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9909445-6-5.html)*
- Брюс Эккель (Bruce Ekkel) — *Философия C++. Введение в стандартный C++*
- Брюс Эккель (Bruce Ekkel) — *Философия C++. Практическое программирование*
- Стенли Липпман, Жози Лажойе, Барбара Э. Му — *Язык программирования C++. Вводный курс (C++ Primer)*
- Стенли Липпман — *Основы программирования на С++. Том 1 (Essential C++)*
- Роберт Лафоре — *Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++*
- [Бьерн Страуструп (Bjarne Stroustrup) — *Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием С++. 2-е изд.  (Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++)](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1949-6.html)*
  Обязательно второе издание - в первом русском издании огромное количество ошибок!
- [Эндрю Кёниг, Барбара Э. Му (Andrew Koenig, Barbara E. Moo) — *Эффективное программирование на C++. Серия книг "C++ In-Depth", 2002](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0350-5.html) ([Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example, 2000](http://www.informit.com/store/accelerated-c-plus-plus-practical-programming-by-example-9780201703535))*
  Учебник по основам C++ для тех, кто уже имеет некоторый опыт программирования на других языках.
- Герберт Шилдт — *C++ базовый курс*
  Существует мнение, что эта книга содержит достаточно много неточностей и ошибок. Тем не менее, она популярна в роли книги для начального обучения.
- Стивен Прата - *Язык программирования C++. Лекции и упражнения. 6-е издание*

## Для среднего уровня

- [Николаи М. Джосаттис (Nicolai M. Josuttis) — *Стандартная библиотека C++: справочное руководство, 2-е издание, 2014](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1837-6.html) ([The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition, 2012](http://www.cppstdlib.com/))*
- Скотт Мейерс (Scott Meyers) — *55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ (Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs)*
- Скотт Мейерс (Scott Meyers) — *Наиболее эффективное использование C++. 35 новых рекомендаций по улучшению ваших программ и проектов (More Effective C++: 35 New Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs)*
- [Герб Саттер — *Решение сложных задач на С++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0352-1.html) (Exceptional C++: 47 Engineering Puzzles, Programming Problems, and Solutions.)*
- [Герб Саттер — *Новые сложные задачи на C++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0823-X.html)  (More Exceptional C++: 40 New Engineering Puzzles, Programming Problems, and Solutions)*
- Бьерн Страуструп (Bjarne Stroustrup) — *Язык программирования С++ (The C++ Programming Language)*
- Андрей Александреску (Andrei Alexandrescu ) — *Современное проектирование на C++ (Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied)*
- [Герб Саттер, Андрей Александреску — *Стандарты программирования на C++*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0859-0.html)
- [Бьярне Страуструп - *Язык программирования С++. Краткий курс, второе издание*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-907144-12-5.html)

## Для высокого уровня

- [Бьерн Страуструп (Bjarne Stroustrup) — *Дизайн и эволюция C++ (The Design and Evolution of C++)*](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/c/978-5-94074-738-3/)
- Стенли Липпман (Stanley Lippman) — *(Inside the C++ Object Model)*
- [Скотт Мейерс — *Эффективный и современный C++ (Effective Modern C++)*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2000-3.html)
- [Питер Готтшлинг — *Современный C++ для программистов, инженеров и ученых (Discovering Modern C++: A Concise Introduction for Scientists and Engineers (C++ In-Depth Series))*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2095-9.html)
- [Курт Гантерот — *Оптимизация программ на C++*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-6-7.html)
- [Дэвид Вандевурд, Николаи М. Джосаттис, Дуглас Грегор *Шаблоны C++. Справочник разработчика, 2-е издание*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9500296-8-4.html)
- [Энтони Уильямс — *Параллельное программирование на С++ в действии*](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/c/978-5-94074-448-1/)
- [Marc Gregoire - *Professional C++ 5th Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119695406)
- [Raymond Chen - *The Old New Thing*: разбор нетривиальных практических проблем при программировании на С++ на Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)

## Документация

[Где взять стандарт C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/181472)

- Е.А. Зуев, А.А. Чупринов *Стандарт С++: перевод, комментарии, примеры.
  — Москва: ООО «ВАШ ФОРМАТ».* — 2016 г. — 888 с.
- [*cppreference.com*: Подробная справка по конструкциям языка и возможностям стандартной библиотеки с примерами](https://cppreference.com/)
- [*C++ FAQ*: частые вопросы по языку](https://isocpp.org/faq)
- [*C++ Core Guidelines*: Указания по "правильному" использованию языка](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

## Несколько слов о выборе книг от сообщества StackOverflow

Все книги, представленные здесь, достаточно хороши ([@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp) [подтверждает](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24381167#24381167), что хорошие книги по программированию есть). Мы постарались сгруппировать их по категориям сложности на основе собственного субъективного мнения. Мы стараемся, чтобы в списке были только хорошие книги, но не сможем выбрать лучшую для вас. Пробуйте читать разные книги и найдите её самостоятельно. Если будет сложно — возьмите попроще, скучно — посложнее.

[@Vlad](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd)  [рекомендует:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24381147#24381147) если вы не можете выбрать сами, берите книгу номером, равным дню вашего рождения % размер списка.

Ещё [@Igumnov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7053/igumnov) [просил передать](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24381320#24381320), что лучше бы вы учили C++ не первым языком. [@PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash) [считает](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24381328#24381328), что можно и первым, но не в коем случае не C перед C++!

Надеюсь, наши субъективные и противоречивые мнения помогли вам понять основную идею: вы должны сами решить, что вам читать и чему учиться. Идеальную, нужную именно вам книгу можете выбрать только вы сами. С уважением, @NickVolynkin.

Вот вам карта, чтобы сориентироваться (картинка кликабельна):

[image: где карта, Билли?]

Comment: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_publications.html

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242)

Comment: http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html

Comment: http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-48036.html

Comment: http://fearlesscoder.blogspot.ru/2012/01/c11-lands.html

Comment: А что бы взять в дорогу не очень толстое? Для начинающего.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1033710/213987) рекомендовали книгу Подбельский В.В. Введение в язык Си++ -- кто-то читал? Хороша, чтобы внести в список?

Comment: @AK я не читал, но вы можете внести её, конечно же )

Comment: Всё что именуется как "для чайников" или "за N дней" и т.п. априори читать не стоит

Answer (score 3):

Для любителей простоты, минимализма и понимаемости того, что делается -  рекомендую книги Андрея Викторовича Столярова (МГУ):

[Введение в язык Си++](http://www.stolyarov.info/books/cppintro)

[Программирование: введение в профессию. Том IV: парадигмы](http://www.stolyarov.info/books/programming_intro/vol4)

Во второй книге он рассказывает про библиотеку графического интерфейса FLTK.
Сам по ним сейчас иду - довольно приятное фундаментальное образование и работающий код получаю.