# Ошибка LNK2019 в пустом проекте

Tags: c++, visual-c++, компиляция, visual-studio-2010

Подскажите почему возникает ошибка

```
error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall mynamespace::testclass::testclass(void)" (??0testclass@mynamespace@@QAE@XZ) в     функции _main
```

Проект по идее пустой, один файл с функцией main и один класс.
Вот коды

файл main.cpp

```
#include "testclass.h"

using namespace mynamespace;

int main() {

testclass *tc = new testclass();

return(0);
}
```

Файл testclass.cpp

```
namespace mynamespace {
    class testclass {
    public:
        testclass() {

        }
    protected:
        ~testclass() {

        }
    public:
        void testmethod() {

        }
    };
}
```

файл testclass.h

```
namespace mynamespace {
    class testclass {
    public:
        testclass(void);
    protected:
        ~testclass();
    public:
        void testmethod();
    };
}
```

Comment: Какой учебник, дайте ссылку

Comment: @Vladimir: Любой. Бумажный. А вообще, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно реализовали функции. У вас должно быть что-то похожее на

```
namespace mynamespace {

    testclass::testcalss() { }

    // ...

}
```

Ваш код нарушает как минимум ODR. И уж правильная форма реализации классов с нужными правилами таки-да есть в каждом учебнике. Не учитесь по онлайн-курсам.

---

Правило, если на пальцах, таково: класс должен быть определён ровно один раз. Это значит, что у вас определение класса должно быть лишь раз, в header'е:

```
class testclass {
    // функции
};
```

(Объявления наподобие `class testclass;` определениями класса не считаются.)

Каждый из методов тоже должен быть определён ровно один раз. Это значит, что каждый метод быть либо определён внутри, прямо в определении класса:

```
class testclass {
public:
    testclass() { }
};
```

либо лишь задекларирован внутри определения класса, и определён отдельно:

```
class testclass {
public:
    testclass();
};

// эта часть уходит в .cpp
testclass::testclass() {
    // код
}
```

Если вы напишете в .cpp новое определение класса, компилятор будет недоволен: определение класса должно быть только одно.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Кстати, насколько помню, когда создаю приложение WinForms, в нем вроде работает та схема с классами которую описал я выше

Comment: @Vladimir: Пожалуйста! С Winforms немного по-другому, т. к. там не чистый C++, а C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Еще понял что решить проблему можно следующим образом.
Раньше у меня в файле testclass.cpp подключался класс testclass.h. По этому и было двойное объявление классов.

Если убрать подключение testclass.h в файле testclass.cpp, то можно объявлять классы так как я описал в своем вопросе. Компилятор не ругается.