# Проблема с выводом массива при попытке написания итератора для массива

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Проблема: не могу вывести числа которые лежат в массиве. Думал, что в методе `value` нужно писать `return *array[current]`, но получаю:

> error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)

Если убрать «разыменовыватель» `return array[current]` то я получаю мусор в выводе

> 1359699216
>   32767
>   0
>   0
>   1359699224
>   32767
>   1359699252
>   32767
>   1359699268
>   32767

Внутри конструктора я «для эксперимента» вписывал цикл, выводящий массив — выводит все очень хорошо. Но когда я пробую возвращать значение через функцию то получаю мусор.

Мне тяжко даются указатели и ссылки, все время путаюсь в них. Если не сложно, можете дать статейку где доступно все расписано?

Реализация:

1. ArrayIterator.cpp

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   class ArrayIterator {
   private:

       int *array;
       int current;
       int size;

   public:

       ArrayIterator(int *array, int size) {
           this->size = size;
           this->current = 0;
       }

       void next() {
           if ( over() ) {
               return;
           }
           current += 1;
       }

       bool over() {
           int last = size - 1;
           return current > last;
       }

       int operator[](int index) {
           return array[index];
       }

       int value() {
           return array[current];
       }
   };
   ```
2. main.cpp:

   ```
   #include "ArrayIterator.cpp"


   int main() {
       int array[10] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
       ArrayIterator seq(array, 10);


       for ( ; !seq.over(); seq.next() ) {
           std::cout << seq.value() << std::endl;
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: В конструкторе итератора не инициализируется поле `array`.

Comment: `array` — массив/указатель, `array[current]` — элемент массива, а не указатель на элемент. Разыменование не нужно. О причине ошибки смотрите предыдущий комментарий.

Answer (score 3):

В конструкторе класса вы забыли проинициализировать член класса `array`

```
ArrayIterator(int *array, int size) {
    this->size = size;
    this->current = 0;
}
```

Конструктор может выглядеть следующим образом

```
ArrayIterator( int *array, int size ) 
    : array( array ), current( 0 ), size( size )
{
}
```

Функции `next` и `over` могут быть написаны проще. Например

```
void next() 
{
    if ( !over() ) ++current;
}

bool over() const
{
    return !( current < size );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Простите, а поле `array` кто будет инициализировать, управдом?

Далее, полистайте Майерса. Разберитесь, что такое списки инициализации в конструкторе и зачем они нужны именно вам. Инициализировать поля так, как это делаете вы — неверно.

Comment: Видимо, человек раньше на `Java` программировал. Там такая запись в порядке вещей.

Comment: @kff да пусть он хоть на медовых бруньках программировал - открыл для себя новый язык, читай лучшие практики применения. Что, Скотт зря старался, клаву топтал? Для таких ведь "умников" дядька трудится.

Comment: @gbg та я только учусь) спасибо за критику и да, невнимательность - это моя беда. но как только отписал тут вопрос сразу и ошибку нашел, вот такая мистика, до этого час сидел и не могу понять что не так

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko: Вам обязательно нужно заглянуть [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105).