# Какие "свежие" книги по C вам известны?

Tags: c, книги

В университете нам твердили, что ничего лучше K&R для изучения C - нет. Сейчас студенты младших курсов интересуются, что из литературы вышло хотя бы приближенного к этой библии по C. Что можно предложить?

Comment: У нас есть [хороший список книг по C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105), но по C кажется нету.

Comment: А в С, что-то кардинально поменялось со времен K&R?

Comment: Советуйте им эту книгу: http://beginners.re/

Comment: У меня на полке стоит этот [справочник](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908911-6-6.html) 2017 года. Кстати, относительно недавно выходила "С для чайников" :) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ничего лучшего, чем [Керниган, Ритчи. Язык программирования C](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-0891-9.html), на мой взгляд, не выходило. Причем эта маленькая книга содержит в себе помимо учебника по языку еще и учебник по хорошей практике программирования.
В C не было таких революционных изменений, как в C++ - вполне можно изучить C89, а потом прочитать о внесенных изменениях (скорее - дополнениях).

Есть еще одна - более современная - хорошая книга по C:
Харбисон, Стил. Язык C с примерами. М.: Бином, 2011.
В ней описан в том числе и стандарт C99. Она написана больше как справочник, но может использоваться и как учебник (даже упражнения есть).

Есть еще современные книги с описанием C11:

- [Прата. Язык программирования C. Лекции и упражнения](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1950-2.html)
- Дейтел, Дейтел. Как программировать на C. М.: Бином, 2014.

К сожалению ничего сказать о них не могу, т.к. сам не читал.
У Дейтелов обычно хорошие книги. Только указанная книга скорее похожа на учебник по *программированию*, в котором за базовый язык принят C (также в ней есть и введение в C++).

Comment: @Abyx Не очень хочется вступать в религиозные дискуссии о том, какой язык лучше. Могу порекомендовать [эту](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/why-code-in-c-anymore/240149452) статью. Про C11 мне известно. Никаких принципиальных изменений в нем не заметил. На русском языке хороших книг об этом стандарте не видел. Также видел только gcc с поддержкой этого стандарта. Embedded компиляторов (основная сфера применения C) - не видел. И, как совершенно верно написано в указанной мною статье, вариант C89 является наиболее переносимым. P.S. Вопросы многопоточности - это отдельная тема.

Comment: По практикам программирования (в основном Си) есть также отличная книжка, которая так и называется -- "Практика программирования" Б. Керниган, Р. Пайк (K&P -- почти K&R :-))

Answer (score 7):

Из совершенно новых хотелось бы отметить "21st Century C"/"Язык С в XXI веке" Бэна Клеменса. Основной упор в книге не сколько на сам язык, сколько на современное инструментальное окружение, полезные библиотеки. Хорошо освещаются изменения в синтаксисе C, которые произошли в последние 20 лет. Изумительное дополнение к какой-нибудь классике вроде K&R.

Comment: Посмотрел оглавление, в самом деле интересно, как там это на 350 страницах изложено. Цена (~1000р) , конечно запредельная.

Comment: Похоже книжка в самом деле хороша (жаль не могу плюсануть дважды :-)). PDF косвенно гуглится через выход на https://forum.reverse4you.org/showthread.php?t=2035

Comment: Есть и перевод: http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/c/978-5-97060-101-3/