# GOTO. Не работает код

Tags: c, goto

Почему не компилируется пример? И где почитать подробнее о goto и других операторах языка?

```
#include<stdio.h>
goto LB1;
LB1:
int main()
{
        printf("hello");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Код* в языке С пишется *внутри функций*. В "чистом поле" снаружи функций писать код бесполезно.

Answer (score 3):

goto можно писать только внутри блока кода, в Вашем случае - внутри main. Нужен для безусловного перехода на указанное label'ом место. [Дейкстра считает](http://hosting.vspu.ac.ru/~chul/dijkstra/goto/goto.htm), что goto не нужен. Но в с иногда без него очень сложно. Где об этом всем почитать - [Какие "свежие" книги по C вам известны?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503204/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Бонус. Минимально переделанный код, что бы "компилировалось".

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    goto LB1;
    printf("hello");
    LB1:
    return 0;
}
```

вот только он ничего выводить не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю *goto* должна быть внутри функции, и она работает только внутри этой функции, т.е. нельзя поставить метку в одной функции, а *goto* в другой