# Как очистить память занятую древовидной структурой?

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево

После выполнения программы на Си, как очистить память занятую древовидной структурой?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <locale.h>


struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
void postorder(struct node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) return;
    postorder(root->left);
    postorder(root->right);
    printf("%d ->", root->data);
}
bool empty_tree(struct node* root)
{
    if (root = NULL) return true;
    else return false;
}

struct node* createNode(value) {
    struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

struct node* insertLeft(struct node* root, int value) {
    root->left = createNode(value);
    return root->left;
}


struct node* insertRight(struct node* root, int value) {
    root->right = createNode(value);
    return root->right;
}


int main() {
    struct node* root = createNode(1);
    insertLeft(root, 12);
    insertRight(root, 9);

    insertLeft(root->left, 5);
    insertRight(root->left, 6);
    printf("\nPostorder traversal \n");
    postorder(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очистка дерева делается классически рекурсивно. Где то так

```
void destroy(struct node* n)
{
  if (n == NULL) return; // если пусто - убегаем
  destroy(n->left);  // почистим левую часть
  destroy(n->right); // почистим правую часть
  free(n);           // ну и саму ноду
}
```

Comment: А как тогда сделать что бы сначала на экран выведены были числа а после уже что память очищена?

Comment: И если можно посоветуйте что почитать по си для новичка так как в универе учебники устаревшие и все слишком заумно написанно

Comment: какие числа и как выведены? Но в любом случае, Вы можете использовать мою функцию как пример, просто вместо free вызывать свою. А там можно как печатать, так и делать что то другое.

Comment: А книги.... это сложно, тут очень индивидуально. Но можно посмотреть темы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503204/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: вводятся числа 5 ->6 ->12 ->9 ->1 ->,а как вот сделать что бы после их вывода сразу очищалась память

Comment: ну  так добавьте после строк `printf("\nPostorder traversal \n");
    postorder(root);` вызов `destroy(root);`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
void delete_tree(struct node* root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        delete_tree(root->left);
        delete_tree(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}
```

PS: Какой смысл дерева, если можно помещать любое значение в любую ветку?