# Какие книги и стандарты актуальны для разработки на чистом Си в 2022-2023 годах?

Tags: c

Не секрет, что книги пишут в основном, опираясь на какую-то школу или документацию, которые устаревают. Какие книги и документы на русском и английском будут актуальны в сфере разработки на языке C в текущем и следующем годах?

Comment: imho как был K&R, так и останется. Ну, еще (тоже как и всегда) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие "свежие" книги по C вам известны?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503204/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b) Главное - не читайте перед обедом K&R

Comment: Книга Кернигана не актуальна почти наполовину.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что есть сейчас :
Текущий стандарт ISO/IEC 9899:2018 - https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html

В 23 году выйдет новый стандарт

Что касается книг - многие именитые деятели возможно выпустят свои новые книги и переиздадут новые издания текущих

На практике ситуация иная - многие все еще изучаю С99 и в малом кол-ве книг есть данные о С11 (ибо изменения действительно малы не считая потоков)

С слишком простой язык и развивается крайне не охотно, а перейти с С99 на С11  и в будущем на С23 будет бесшовным по причине мелких изменений (ожидать труды как Майерса не стоит по С)

Так что ответ - да книги будут актуальны на 99-95% по составу информации

Comment: А Майерс что написал?

Comment: @Грузчик У него целя серия книг по С++ по типу "Эффективное использование C++"