# Программирование на языке C++

Tags: c++

Я изучаю и занимаюсь программированием на языке С++, и довольно хорошо освоил базовые знания, могу решать разного рода задачи. Вопрос: с чего начать углубленное изучение языка программирования?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите интересный вам opensorce-проект и пытайтесь понять его. Если ощутите нехватку знаний, то гуглите в направлении непонимания.

Comment: Извините,а где я могу найти большой выбор opensource-проектов? Есть ли отдельный сайт или самому гуглить? Было бы хорошо, если бы вы посоветовали какой нибудь проект. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @SH5427 есть такой сайт - github.com

Comment: спс)) уже туда и зашёл))

Comment: @SH5427 Еще есть gitlab.com/explore и некоторые проекты, которых нет на гитхабе, можно поискать просто в гугле, скажем, если вам интересен GIMP, то его репозитории можно найти [здесь](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Мэйерс С. Эффективное использование C++
2. Параллельное программирование на С++ в действии. Энтони Уильямс
3. Скотт Мейерс - Наиболее эффективное использование C++