# Forward Declaration, по какой причине возникает мусор в публичных полях?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Код:**

```
// Main.cpp
#include <thread>
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include "ChildClass.h"

// Объект базового класса
BaseNamespace::BaseClass baseClass;

void Show()
{
    printf("%u\r\n", ((ChildNamespace::ChildClass *)baseClass.obj)->ShowPrivateInt());
    printf("%u\r\n", ((ChildNamespace::ChildClass *)baseClass.obj)->ShowPublicInt()); // Выводит мусор вместо числа: 2
    printf("%u\r\n", ((ChildNamespace::ChildClass *)baseClass.obj)->ChildPublicInt); // Выводит мусор вместо числа: 2
}

int main()
{
    auto th1 = std::thread(Show);
    auto th2 = std::thread(Show);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
// BaseClass.h
#pragma once

namespace BaseNamespace
{
    class ChildClass;
    class BaseClass
    {
    public:
        BaseClass();
        ~BaseClass();
        ChildClass *obj;
    };
}
```

---

```
// BaseClass.cpp
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include "ChildClass.h"

namespace BaseNamespace
{
    BaseClass::BaseClass()
    {
        this->obj = (BaseNamespace::ChildClass *)&ChildNamespace::ChildClass((ChildNamespace::BaseClass *)this);
    }

    BaseClass::~BaseClass()
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
// ChildClass.h
#pragma once

namespace ChildNamespace
{
    class BaseClass;
    class ChildClass
    {
    public:
        ChildClass(ChildNamespace::BaseClass *obj);
        ~ChildClass();
        int ShowPrivateInt();
        int ShowPublicInt();

        BaseClass *baseObj;

        int ChildPublicInt; // Проблема тут, выводит мусор при вызове из класса Main
    };
}
```

---

```
// ChildClass.cpp
#include "ChildClass.h"

namespace ChildNamespace
{
    int ChildPrivateInt = 7;

    ChildClass::ChildClass(BaseClass *obj)
    {
        this->baseObj = obj;
            ChildPublicInt = 2;
    }

    int ChildClass::ShowPrivateInt()
    {
        return ChildPrivateInt;
    }

    int ChildClass::ShowPublicInt()
    {
        return ChildPublicInt;
    }

    ChildClass::~ChildClass()
    {
    }
}
```

---

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Как объявить публичное поле в ChildClass по значению (а не по ссылке или указателю)? Почему компилятор не выдает даже предупреждения? Почему подобное вообще возникает и куда смотрели разработчики C++ (даже в учебниках по C++ не встречал подобной проблемы)?

**Проект:** [ссылка](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8z5dxr)

Comment: Попробуйте предоставить [mcve].

Comment: @alexolut, так я и предоставил минимально возможный пример, 2 класса и класс Main, минимальнее некуда.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил комментарии и вывод.

Comment: Для начала можно весь код привести в одном файле. Это уже будет меньше, и по-крайней мере позволит быстро проверить его на компиляцию и запуск. Просто представьте сколько лишних действий нужно сделать тому, кто собирается Вам помочь, имея несколько исходников вместо одного.

Comment: @alexolut, дабы избежать риск изменения поведения - не стал лепить все в один файл. Выложил как есть, корректно, с разными неймспейсами, .h и .cpp файлами классов.

Comment: Просто может статься, что в процессе уменьшения кода Вы сами найдете ошибку без чужой помощи. А это бывает куда приятнее разобраться самому.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил линк на проект. Тут не во мне дело. Тут дело в Forward Declaration классов. Я вообще не понимаю как создатели плюсов (который изначально планировался как язык с поддержкой ООП) - допустили такое. И как Visual Studio, самая продвинутая IDE на данный момент - пропустила эту ошибку, даже не выдав предупреждения. Масса негативныйх имоций...

Comment: А можно разве делать инициализацию в заголовочных файлах? Мне казалось что там только объявление...

Comment: ChildPublicInt насколько я вижу не инициализирован в конструкторе, отсюда и мусор

Comment: ChildPrivateInt вообще не член класса, а глобальная переменная неймспейса, а обращение через интерфейс класса. Странное архитектурное решение

Comment: @vldmalov, добавил инициализацию ChildPublicInt = 2; в конструкторе ChildClass::ChildClass(BaseClass *obj) - поведение не изменилось. Мусор не исчез.

Comment: И ещё в конструкторе BaseClass конструируя obj зачем-то приводите this к своему же типу BaseClass*. Как говорили на уроках литературы - масло масленное. В обще зря вы пеняете на разработчиков C++, тут дело не в них

Comment: @All, я повторюсь, проблема именно в Forward Declaration, если вызывать класс напрямую - все работает стабильно.

Comment: @vldmalov, по поводу конструктора - как же по Вашему правильно сделать приведение типов в этом случае? Возможно проблема именно в этом.

Comment: @user152132 ChildClass конструируется указателем на BaseClass. Создавая this->obj просто передавайте this без приведения. Это не влияет на работу, просто лишнее приведение, которого не должно быть

Comment: @vldmalov, тогда получается ошибка каста. Обратите внимание что неймспейсы у классов разные.

Comment: @pavel это `in-class` инициализация, начиная с `c++11`.

Comment: @alexolut, благодарю, оветил на вопрос павла и нечайно удалил свой комментарий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код жуткий (и это ещё слабо сказано), но обозначенная Вами проблема возникает из-за сохранения адреса локального (временного) объекта, который будет уничтожен по выходу из блока. Замените:

```
this->obj = (BaseNamespace::ChildClass *)&ChildNamespace::ChildClass((ChildNamespace::BaseClass *)this);
```

например на:

```
this->obj = (BaseNamespace::ChildClass *)(new ChildNamespace::ChildClass((ChildNamespace::BaseClass *)this));
```

И вывод уже будет ожидаем:

> 7
>   2 
>   2

Если абстрагироваться от лишних потоков исполнения.

Comment: Код не жуткий) Код вполне обычный если говорить об управляемых ЯП (C#, Java и т.д.) - где классы - ссылочные типы.

Comment: Один вопрос - как корректно (и нужно ли вообще) освободить  память выделенную оператором new в данном случае?

Comment: @user152132 вызвать в нужный момент времени `delete obj;` Конечно нужно, это же не Ваши любимые УЯПы :)

Comment: Благодарю за грамотный ответ. Вот только почему то этот момент забывают освещать авторы учебников и технической литературы.

Comment: @user152132 видимо, Вы не ту литературу осваиваете. Вот [списочек](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1) есть.

Comment: Спасибо за литературу, вот только боюсь в этом списке едва ли вообще будет затронута данная тема. Я читал Рихтер Дж., Назар К. - Windows via C C++, там не освещен этот аспект.

Comment: Читайте первоисточник - Б. Страуструпа.

Comment: @aleks.andr в оригинале :)