# Сумма чисел от 1 до n. C++

Tags: c++

[Здесь](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/contests/7861/problems/65484)

Найти сумму от `1` до `n`.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    cin >> n;

    if (n<=-1) for(int i=1; i>=n; i--) sum+= i; // сума отрицательных
    else sum = (1+n) * n / 2; // по формуле

    cout << sum;
}
```

Скорее всего, программа не проходит по времени. Посоветуйте алгоритм пожалуйста.
**В чем подвох этой задачи?**

Comment: тип long long и `if` измените, там цикл в другую сторону

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши главные ошибки - во-первых, вы не учитываете, что сумма может быть на все 64 бита... Соответственно, суммировать циклом - это кошмарное решение.

Нельзя даже множить `n*(n+1)/2` - потому что можно получить переполнение!

Нужно, например, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long long n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n > 0)
    {
        if (n%2)
            n = ((n+1) >> 1)*n;
        else
            n = (n >> 1)*(n+1);
    }
    else if (n==0) n = 1;
    else
    {
        n = -n;
        if (n%2)
            n = ((n+1) >> 1)*n;
        else
            n = (n >> 1)*(n+1);
        n = 1 - n;
    }
    cout << n << endl;

}
```

Comment: Деление на 2 :)

Comment: Ну, знаете... Да не волнуйтесь, я за вас уже и на e-olymp решение отправил :) Я написал достаточно, чтоб хоть немного подумать самому. Лень думать - копируйте код и отправляйте.

Comment: Именно! Потому что все очень примитивно, я и не буду разжевывать дальше. Хватило бы подсказки - что 1. число должно быть большим, 2. произведение n*(n+1) может приводить к переполнению, 3. нельзя использовать цикл - не хватит времени...

Comment: Я же написал - **деление на 2**.

Comment: Я не злюсь, а раздражаюсь :)

Comment: Можно `int64_t` использовать. И если вы пишите `n>>1` вместо `n/2`, то логичнее использовать `n&1` вместо `n%2` (компилятор скорее всего одинаковый код генерирует). Если беспокоиться о переполнениях, то за `-(1<<63)` можно упомянуть.