# Функция которая групирует значения в векторе

Tags: c++, vector

Я написал функцию,  но  компилятор кричит что есть ошибки. Но я не знаю что не так. Посмотрите п лиз. Оно кричит  на 8 строку  и  на іf

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>> GroupGameObjectsByMaterial(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>> gameObjects)
{
    for (std::shared_ptr<GameObject> gameObject : *gameObjects)
    {
        std::sort(*gameObjects->begin(), *gameObjects->end(), Comp);
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>> gameObjectsByMaterial;
    gameObjectsByMaterial.reserve(gameObjects->size);

    for (auto it = gameObjects->begin(); it != gameObjects->end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it != gameObjectsByMaterial[gameObjectsByMaterial.size - 1])
        {
            gameObjectsByMaterial.push_back(it);
        }
    }
    return gameObjectsByMaterial;
}
```

Проблемные строки:

```
  if (it != gameObjectsByMaterial[gameObjectsByMaterial.size() - 1])
    {
        gameObjectsByMaterial.push_back(*it);
    }
```

Ошыбки:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'void std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<GameObject>' to 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&'   GameLoader

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>>>]" matches the argument list   GameLoader  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      no operator "!=" matches these operands GameLoader
```

Comment: а какой прикол ставить автору -1 ? Или все  гуру тут собралися?)

Comment: минус пока не ставлю, но вопрос требует уточнения (для этого есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/676041/edit)). 1. Проблемные строки можно было хотя бы комментарием пометить, или пронумеровать все, раз уж ссылаетесь на номер. 2. Как именно ругается компилятор? приведите текст ошибки (текстом разумеется, а не скриншотом)

Comment: @rdorn скинул в  дополнения

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых стоит начать с того, что `size` это метод класса `vector`, да и любого контейнера. Поэтому её надо вызывать:

```
gameObjectsByMaterial.size
```

стоит заменить на

```
gameObjectsByMaterial.size()
```

---

Во-вторых в `if` вы сравниваете `it`, который является итератором с элементом вектора `gameObjectsByMaterial`, который имеет тип `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>`. Разумеется, оператор `!=` для них не определен. И даже если разименовать итератор (`*it`), то получится объект типа `std::shared_ptr<GameObject>`, который тоже нельзя сравнить с вектором из этих элементов. Что вы на самом деле хотите сравнить?

---

В-третьих посмотрим на сортировку:

```
for (auto gameObject : *gameObjects)  // заменил тип на auto
{
    std::sort(*gameObjects->begin(), *gameObjects->end(), Comp);
}
```

Можно заметить, что `gameObject` внутри тела цикла никак не используется. То есть мы сколько-то раз вызываем сортировку от одних и тех же аргументов. Зачем? Одного раза вполне хватит, чтобы отсортировать. Более того. Посмотрим, переменные каких типов мы туда передаём: `*gameObjects->begin()`. [Приоритет](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `->` выше. Значит сначала мы получим итератор объекта std::vector<...>, а потом его зачем-то разыменуем и получим `shared_ptr<GameObject>`, который отправим в `sort`, но `sort` то хочет итератор. И предавать туда тоже хотите итератор, не так ли? Что на самом деле вы сортируете?

---

Вероятно то, что вы хотите делается так в пару строк:

```
auto sort_del_dup(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>> gameObjects) {
    std::sort(gameObjects->begin(), gameObjects->end(), Comp); // отсортировали
    gameObjects->erase(std::unique(gameObjects->begin(), gameObjects->end(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
        return *lhs == *rhs;
    }), gameObjects->end());
}
```

сначала отсортируем, а потом удалим одинаковые объекты.

Comment: А закончить тем, что такие страшные вещи, как "std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>>" стоит выносить в typedef, а лучше в два :)

Comment: мне  нужно чтобы  значения  не повторялися. Например 11 22 456  мне  нужно чтобы  только по одному разу записалось  например 123456

Comment: а как  тогда иф  переделать чтобы   програма работала?

Comment: @dimaAf Вы хотите в результате получить двумерный массив. Какой?

Comment: @retorta, нет у меня есть вектор  с значениями. я их хочу  отсортировать  и вывести на екран.  но чтобы  они  не повторялись. поэтому и  делаю иф  проверку  чтобы  соседи не  были  однаковые. поэтому я  и создаю еще  один вектор  записываю  туда  уже  остортированые значения и вывожу его на екран

Comment: @dimaAf `std::vector<std::vector< ... > >` Это двумерный вектор. Что вы хотите в нём видеть?

Comment: @retorta, как я уже говорил  значения мне туда нужно записать , новые

Comment: @dimaAf Я дополнил ответ тем, что как мне кажется вам нужно, но очень советую вам найти какую-нибудь [хорошую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1) книгу по С++. Мне пока кажется, что вы вообще не понимаете, что происходит.