# Подготовка к CPA exam

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Я собираюсь здать тест **CPA**. Из подготовки: прошел курс Essentials in C++ (И получил ваучер на скидку) и университетский курс с++ ( семестр)

Помогите, пожалуйста, с *литературой* (можно и *английскую*) и *ресурсами* для качаственной подготовки к экзамену.
Мне не нужна любая литература, нужно чтото провереное, просто литературу по с++ можно и в гугле найти.

Кто уже завал этот экзамен, как оно? Какие подводные камни можно встретить при здаче экзамена?

Comment: [Список литературы по C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/176217)

Comment: И чем вам «просто литература» не угодила?