# Продвинутое изучение С++

Tags: c++

Всем здравствуйте. Недавно прошел курс по основам С++ от Яндекса. Там был рассмотрен синтаксис, процедурное программирование и основы ООП. Также работа с фалами, перегрузка операторов и пр. Теперь возник вопрос, а как двигаться дальше? Не очень хочется заново читать из литературы то ,что ты уже прошел и подкрепил задачами. Может кто посоветовать, как продвигаться дальше? Может быть книги, или сайты с уроками, подходящие не совсем для новичков.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105

Comment: Начни писать код. Подумай, что хотел бы ты сделать и начни это. Если не практиковаться, то из головы быстро всё улетучится.

Comment: @VladD, а чего дублем-то не закрыл?

Comment: @Grundy: Засомневался чёта.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уже знаете азы то по моему опыту и думаю опыту всех программистов вам следует как сказали в комментариях начать писать код. А как и где его писать это уже ваш выбор. Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Пишите код своего проекта. Это будет интересно. Если у вас конечно его проект.
2. Найдите open source проект и помогайте им. Большинство проектов будут только рады помощи и сообщество поможет вам, но не думайте что вас будут учить кодить. Работая над опенсоррс проектом вы научитесь не только писать код, но и читать.