# Разница постфиксной и префиксной записи

Tags: c++

Читал книгу Прата, у него было написано что постфиксная запись работает быстрее, но дальше в своей книге в цикле `for` использовал запись префиксную. Почему он ей пользовался если сам писал, что это медленнее.

Comment: Так надо у него и спрашивать. А вообще, если хотите какого-то внятного ответа, приведите цитаты, ссылку на книгу (название, издание) и страницы. Может быть тогда что-то получится ответить.

Comment: Вы бы лучше почитали книги посвежее. Эта информация устарела уже лет 10 как. Современные компиляторы неплохо умеют для (простых) участков кода с одинаковой семантикой генерировать одинаковый объектный код.

Comment: alexolut, Прата С. - Язык программирования C++. Лекции и упражнения - 2011.
219 стр.  2 обзац. "Сравнение префиксной и постфиксной форм " 6 издание (может быть на 217 стр. т.к. у меня эл. версия и первые 2 стр. по сути мусорные)

Comment: VladD, читаю, потому что посоветовали сказали что для начала неплохая книжка простая и понятная с хорошим кол-вом информации.

Comment: Список рекомендуемой литературы можете посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454264/176217).

Comment: Для уведомления другого участника в комментариях нужно добавлять символ `@` сразу перед ником. И существенную часть стоит вносить в вопрос путём его правки, а не добавлением комментария.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это о префиксном и постфиксном инкременте/декременте...

Формально постфиксная должна работать медленнее, так как она делает то же, что и префиксная, но еще и возвращает старое значение. Т.е., грубо говоря -

```
var++
```

это

```
type oldvalue = var;
++var;
return oldvalue;
```

Но все современные компиляторы для простых типов вполне способны выполнить оптимизацию. А для классов с пользовательскими операторами скорее важно, что вы сами там напишете :)

Comment: Так у ТС наоборот указано "постфиксная запись работает быстрее".

Comment: @alexolut А я и объясняю, что это ерунда. Либо автор ошибся, либо переводчик.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо просто хотел узнать почему так написано, а потом совсем другое