# Что с кодом не так?

Tags: c++

Я ввел с клавиатуры число, допустим меньше нуля, и должно быть написано введено не верно..и типа console.readkey но ток на c++ , ну типа надо прописать диапазон, что можно вводить скажем от -5 до 400 else введено не верно...типа так...

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "sstream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    int x = 0;
    if (x < 0)
        std::cout << "Error, try again...";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где в вашем коде ввод числа?

Comment: читать символ - `cin.get`

Comment: @VladD, getchar же, очевидно :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Туплю чёта :-D

Comment: @VladD хз, я c++ не знаю вообще, поэтому и не удивительно что банальность не верна...в нете нахожу и слеиваю код :|

Comment: @Unknown: А вы не пробовали сначала прочитать книжку? Я знаю многих людей, которым такое помогло.

Comment: @VladD почитать это конечно дело хорошее, но вот так....:<|

Comment: @Unknown: У нас даже список есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105

Comment: "Я даже подумал: уж не выучить ли мне в конце концов эту анатомию, а потом решил пока этого не делать." Виктор Голявкин "Я жду Вас всегда с интересом." http://smartfiction.ru/prose/waiting_interest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // объявляем переменную
    int x;

    // выводим на экран приглашение
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";

    // считываем данные из стандартного потока ввода в переменную x
    std::cin >> x;

    // проверяем условие попадания в диапазон и выводим результат
    if (x >= -5 && x <= 400)
        std::cout << "Ok.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот, использовал такую заготовку при выполнении работ нерадивым студентам :)

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
}
```

Думаю, если что - допилите напильником...