# Как скомпилировать программку в notepad++

Tags: c++, c, компиляция, notepad++

Я знаю, как компилировать программку в **Sublime Text 3**. *Надо просто нажать клавишу **F7***. В **Notepad++** непонятно, как компилировать программку на **C/C++**. Версия **Notepad++ V6.9**. Плагин **NppExec** установлен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите опытные разработчики.

Comment: 1. Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном. 2. Прочитайте документацию к плагину, которым устраиваете компиляцию.

Comment: По второй части вопроса - [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)