# Посоветуйте материалы по межпроцессному взаимодействию

Tags: c++

Синтаксис языка освоил, есть понятие базовых алгоритмов (на уровне решения прикладных задач) и понятие ООП.

Появилось задание, создать приложение, которым можно будет получать данные из другого приложения, а так же иметь возможность управлять этим приложением (редактировать данные).

Не знаю что учить. Понимаю, что скорее всего это WinAPI, но не уверен. С чего начать и куда двигаться далее? (в условиях ограниченного времени)

Comment: Вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105

Comment: Все же это изучение не С++, а межпроцессного взаимодействия, что не совсем одно и то же, так что вопрос - не совсем дубликат.

Comment: Читайте вот это: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Harry: В начальной ревизии текст был другой