# Конструктор с параметрами и по умолчанию

Tags: c++, конструктор

```
class AB 
{
    private:
    int a;
    int b;
    public:
    AB()    
    {
        a = 10;
        b = 10;
    } 
};

class AB 
{
    private:
    int a;
    int b;

    public:
    AB(int A, int B) 
    {
        a = A;
        b = B;
    }
};
```

Два отрывка кода. В ПЕРВОМ случае мы сразу инициализируем переменные в конструкторе, а во ВТОРОМ случае мы будем инициализировать при создании объекта. Зачем тогда было "придумывать" конструкторы с параметрами если как и в ПЕРВОМ случае можно сразу задать значения внутри конструктора и все. Не знаю, может мой вопрос глупый. Не судите. Я новичок

Comment: ну, чтобы иметь возможность создавать разные объекты. В первом варианте каждый новый объект (создаваемый вызовом конструктора: `AB()`) будет иметь одинаковые значения полей `a` и `b` (равные 10). А во втором варианте можно создавать объекты, значения полей `a` и `b` которых будут разные: `AB(0,0)` или `AB(7,5)` и много других

Comment: А что будет если оставить конструктор вообще пустым? Без тела, без параметров.

Comment: @MarynaSaid члены останутся неинициализированными, проще говоря, там будет мусор.

Comment: Мне что-то это * можно сразу задать значения внутри конструктора* перефразируется в - зачем в функции `sqrt(x)` параметр `x`?! Его же можно задать прямо внутри функции `sqrt()` и всё!

Comment: @Harry sqrt42() :)

Comment: @alexolut Тогда уж `sqrt<42>()`...

Comment: @Harry ну, функция-то сишная, пусть её и остаётся. Обёртку шаблонную конечно можно и написать.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, это не инициализация, а присваивание. Для инициализации членов есть специальный синтаксис вида:

```
AB() : a(10), b(10)
```

Это если для первого варианта. Далее идёт тело конструктора с фигурными скобками. Начиная с с++11 можно инициализировать члены по месту, то есть при определении класса.

Во-вторых, можно сделать единый конструктор с параметрами по умолчанию:

```
AB(int A = 10, int B = 10) : a(A), b(B) { }
```

Он позволит вам создавать объект с любым количеством параметров: от нуля до двух.

В-третьих, обо всём этом написано в любом учебнике по языку. Просто не торопитесь, а почитайте чуть дальше, чтобы понять.

Список литературы можете почерпнуть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/176217).