# Как создать динамический массив структур?

Tags: c++

```
struct Rabbit {
int X;
int Y;
bool death = true;
bool finder = true;
int counter = 0;
};
```

Объясните мне пожалуйста как неандертальцу, как создать динамический массив структур, желательно с адекватным примером

Comment: Что такое "динамический массив"? Массив, хранящийся в динамической памяти? Или массив переменного размера?

Comment: Мне нужен масив переменного размера

Comment: [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) не пробовали?

Comment: Я не знаю что это

Comment: @МаксимСтарий: Отлично, [самое время узнать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/10105).

Answer (score 1):

Для создания динамических массивов в C++ можно использовать контейнер [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct SomeStruct {
    int num;
    std::string str;
};

int main(void) {
    /* Можно создать вектор и сразу инициализировать его. */
    std::vector<struct SomeStruct> vec = {
        {10, "first"},
        {20, "second"}
    };

    /* Первый способ добавления структуры в вектор. */
    vec.push_back({30, "third"});

    /* Второй способ. */
    vec.push_back(SomeStruct());
    vec.back().num = 40;
    vec.back().str = "fourth";

    /* Третий способ. */
    struct SomeStruct const temp = {50, "fifth"};
    vec.push_back(temp);

    /* Выводим все элементы вектора. */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vec[i].num << " " + vec[i].str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот [ответ на ваш вопрос. На С++](http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=3567)

---

А вот мой ответ, он на Qt.

тут будет немного "лишнего" кода для понимания куда я его прописывал код.

**mainwindows.h**

```
typedef struct
{
        int              ID;      // переменная структуры
 } Str_Message; // создаём структуру

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

     QVector <Str_Message> S_M;  // задаём вектор в который будем  складывать созданные структуры

    Str_Message  struc_mess; //Чтобы поместить в структуру в вектор, надо что бы структура была объявлена. объявляем структуру.
```

**mainwindows.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    struc_mess.ID = 1; // заполняю структуру
    S_M.append(struc_mess); //Поместили одну структуру. 
    struc_mess.ID = 2; // заполняю структуру 
    S_M.append(struc_mess);  //Поместили еще одну структуру

    qDebug() << "S_M.at(0).ID :" << S_M.at(0).ID; // "по точечно" проверяем что там лежит
    qDebug() << "S_M.at(1).ID :" << S_M.at(1).ID;

    for (QVector<Str_Message>::iterator it=S_M.begin();it!=S_M.end();it++)
        qDebug() << "ID : " << it->ID; // выводим то что лежит в структурах
}
```

Comment: А причем здесь Qt?

Comment: @eanmost Qt это фраемворк для С++, если не использовать инструмент  сигналов и слотов  в qt, по существу это С++

Comment: Я прекрасно представляю себе, что такое Qt, но автор вопроса поставил метку [tag:C++], а не [tag:Qt]. Следовательно, и ответ должен быть *без* Qt.

Comment: @eanmos я поставил ссылку на ответ на С++ и дополнил своим способом. Qt очень близок, по этому и дополнил своим способом.

Comment: Представьте, что какому-то новичку нужно создать «динамический массив структур на C++». Через гугл он находит этот вопрос и ваш ответ, соответственно. Сможет ли он, исходя из вашего ответа решить свою проблему? Нет, ведь у него нет Qt, и он не знает, что это! Теперь вместо одной проблемы у него — три: узнать о Qt, скачать Qt, и, собственно, создать свой динамический массив. Я, конечно, утрирую, но все же... По поводу вашей ссылки, да моему новичку она поможет, но тогда получается, что это ответ-ссылка, а такое не приветствуется.

Comment: @eanmos могу скопировать тот код, из ссылки и выложить его с минимальными изменениями (хотя пару переменных переименую чтоб не сильно было похоже "хотя архитектура будет та же самая" ). Переносить ??

Comment: @eanmos я проверил ваш вариант ,он прекрасно работает. Считаю что лучше чтобы вы сами выложили ваш ответ с комментариями "почему первый ответ не совсем по теме".