# Как реализуется iтая переменная в C++

Tags: c++, синтаксис

Допустим у меня серия уравнений, и выходит так, x(2) это x(1) - n (и далее это тоже продолжается). Можно ли как-то задать один раз переменную x, чтобы под нее попадало столько иксов, сколько мне нужно? а желательно i иксов, чтобы это еще потом подсчитать отдельно и задать, например по введеному значению в cout от пользователя. Это имеет какое-то отношение к i++ или ++i ?

Comment: нет, это "имеет отношение" к массивам

Comment: Почитайте мануал по с.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет полезен этот вопрос: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй численные массивы:

```
int a[5]; //Создать массив из 5и элементов, пустой, целочисленный тип
int b[2] = {1, 2}; //создать массив из 2х элементов, целочисленный тип
```

где b[1] - элемент массива под номером 1 (нумерация с 0)