# Не работает функция setWindowTitle Qt

Tags: qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString str = "Hello";
    QWidget::setWindowTitle ( "Hello" );
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Данный код не работает, почему?! беру с сайта документации. Этот кьюит вообще не понятный!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разберем все то что вы написали по строчно:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv); // создали экземпляр класса `QApplication`
QString str = "Hello"; // Не понятно зачем объявили строку `QString`
QWidget::setWindowTitle ( "Hello" ); // вызвали статический метод у класса `QWidget`
MainWindow w; // Только после этого объявили переменную типа `MainWindow`
w.show(); // Вызвали метод `show`
return a.exec(); // Запустили цикл обработки сообщений приложения
```

> Q: Почему это не работает?

Данный код **работает** правильно, именно так как вы и написали.

> Q: Почему работает неправильно?

Потому что вам необходимо вызвать метод `void setWindowTitle(const QString&)` у экземпляра класса `MainWindow` (*В данном случае это переменная `w`*).

```
w.setWindowTitle("Hello");
```

Аналогом может быть вызов статического метода `QWidget::setWindowTitle()`. Но только если вы это сделаете прямо в наследуемом классе `MainWindow`.

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
public:
    MainWindow() : QWidget(nullptr)
    {
        // Это конструктор класса

        QWidget::setWindowTitle("Hello");
    }
// дальше могут идти методы, поля, класс показан как минимальный пример
};
```

Comment: Аналогом может быть вызов статического метода QWidget:setWindowTitle(). Но только если вы это сделаете прямо в наследуемом классе MainWindow. а как вот это сделать?

Comment: @Анатолий: Такое можно сделать только внутри методов которые вы объявляете/перегружаете от класса `QWidget`. Как пример в конструкторе.

Comment: Можете показать на коде, если не сложно

Comment: @Анатолий: Я конечно добавил пример кода, но вам стоит почитать о том что такое `ООП C++`.

Comment: буду читать. только какую литературу лучше?

Comment: @Анатолий: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1

Answer (score 4):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv); 
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle ( "Hello" );
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Qt не виноват, Вы не понимаете базовые принципы c++

Comment: а сайте оф документации указано вообще void setWindowTitle ( const QString & ) , ну и?!

Comment: так а разве это неправда? все так и есть.

Comment: а что я не правильно делал?

Comment: так посмотрите чем мой код отличается от Вашего.

Comment: вижу. но почему так? в документации такого нет