# Хочу написать приложение

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

Я новичок, изучаю С++ и для практики хочу написать (может списать) приложение похожее на ankiapp. Ankiapp - это карточки для запоминания, например, английских слов. То есть на одной стороне английское слово, а на другой перевод.
С чего мне начать? Может где-то можно чей-то код стырить?
Для создания GUI взял wxWidgets.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: _Может где-то можно чей-то код стырить?_ Гениальный вопрос при изучении, попробуйте заложить собственную логику в разработку. Ибо взяв чужой код, я уверен, вы в полный принцип его работы вникать не будете, оставив так как есть. Пробуйте, экспериментируйте и будет результат на лицо. :)

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий, какой ответ вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: @Tivyram так вы можете подсказать с чем мне пробовать, с чем эксперементировать? Какие например базы данных, может материалы какие-нибудь?

Comment: @GreenDragon может ссылки на материалы какие-нибудь или может какую-нибудь стандартную стратегию, которой обычно придерживаются. Короче ситуация такая, почитав немного Стивена Прата я решил, что хочу попробовать что-нибудь поделать, попрактиковаться. Может я конечно нос задрал и мне пока рано это делать. Вот я и решил узнать. Не понял почему вопрос "слишком общий". Вроде конкретно, есть задача (написать приложение), даже расписан небольшой функционал этого приложения, написан язык. Какие еще уточнения нужны?

Comment: @RomanAr Начните с простого, потом увеличивайте сложность. Не берите сразу сложную задачу. Разбейте задачу на множество небольших. Начните с какого либо окна, потом сделайте дополнение к нему и расширяйте функционал. Вам для начала надо получить понятие, как что работает. Разработайте алгоритм работы приложения: Что должен делать пользователь? Как система должна реагировать на его действия? Когда вы ответите на эти вопросы вы уже будете знать с чего начать.

Comment: Какие именно материалы вас интересуют? 
Стандартная стратегия есть, её суть можно выразить известной цитатой "Первым шагом является формирование видения, потому что когда у вас есть видение своей цели — ее прекрасный образ, — это создает силу желания". В вашем вопросе я не вижу определенности, так что на мой взгляд он слишком общий.

Comment: Но если хотите знать мое мнение, то вам начать нужно с прокачки умения задавать вопросы, а для этого их нужно задавать. Для начала - самому себе. После - кошке/утке/подруге.... Затем - поисковику, после - здесь или на других ресурсах. Вам выше дали хороший совет - разбить задачу на небольшие и шаг за шагом её выполнять. Так что берите wxwidgets и вперед.