# Актуальна ли книга С. Прата С++ 6-издание 2011г.?

Tags: c++, книги

Стоит ли читать С. Прата С++ 6-издание  2011г. в 2018-ом?

Comment: Как я считаю, любую полезную книгу стоит читать, насколько она стара не была бы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вполне актуальна. Стандарт C++11 в ней рассмаривается достаточно подробно, изменения в последующих стандартах понадобятся только с приобретением опыта и о них можно почитать отдельно в первоисточниках или просто в интернете. Но должен придупредить, книга очень объемная, местами даже излишне, лично мне читать было тяжело.