# вычисление jsmath в браузере

Tags: c++

Доброго времени
этого не пишут в учебниках
хочу заставить Лису(FF) вычислять math функцию внутри браузера, а не через Windows (ADVAPI32.DLL Function36).
Но при компиляции измененного кода постоянно получаю ошибки.
Я конечно кривые коды пишу, но пытаюсь подстроиться под исходный С++.

Например: в файл jsmath.cpp подгружаю

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random> 
#include <algorithm>
.........
.........
double
js::math_random_no_outparam(JSContext* cx)
{
    if JSContext* == "Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)"
    {
              return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
       return random_nextDouble(&cx->compartment()->rngState);
}
........
```

в итоге не видит и не распознает ни рандом, ни фло, ни мат, ни джиэс контекст
Подскажите в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: @VTT а причём тут книги?

Comment: @alexolut Ну тут человеку явно стоит начать с основ C++ чтобы так не плавать.

Comment: да мне учебники мало помогут, я в коде даже () забыл прописать

Comment: вероятно такой код тоже не будет работать:
double
js::math_random_no_outparam(JSConte xt* cx)
{
if (JSContext* == "Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)")
{
void main()
{
Random^ rnd = new Random();
{
int max, min;
rnd->Next(max, min);
}
}
}
return random_nextDouble(&cx->compartment()->rngState);
}

....тогда как быть?
если надо, чтобы при событии и исполнения строки Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) в JS срабатывал именно прописанный рандом браузера...

Comment: вероятно такой код тоже не будет работать:
double
js::math_random_no_outparam(JSConte xt* cx)
{
if (JSContext* == "Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)")
{
void main()
{
Random^ rnd = new Random();
{
int max, min;
rnd->Next(max, min);
}
}
}
return random_nextDouble(&cx->compartment()->rngState);
}

....тогда как быть?
если надо, чтобы при событии и исполнения строки Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) в JS срабатывал именно прописанный рандом браузера...

Comment: Не пихайте код в комментарии. Дополните вопрос, напишите что именно вы пытаетесь сделать: расширение к Firefox, собственный форк Firefox или что-то еще