# Изучение C++ онлайн инерактивно

Tags: c++

Есть ли что-нибудь похожее на Codecademy, но для C++? Для изучения языка интерактивно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: Что вы уже предприняли, чтобы  найти ответ на поставленный вами вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще недавно работал сайт [academy.cppstudio.com](http://academy.cppstudio.com), но, к сожалению, он уже не работает. Поэтому приведу другие любимые сайты.

[image: Stepic]

1. [Stepic](https://welcome.stepik.org/ru) - мощнейшая платформа для создания курсов. Здесь уже опубликованы обучающие уроки по C++ и Java, а также многим другим языкам программирования. Формат уроков следующий - видео/теория, и, конечно же, практика! Все задания и код проверяются автоматически.

[image: HackerRank]

2. [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) - портал для программистов и хакеров. Здесь можно изучить как C++, так и Java. Сайт англоязычный, поэтому тут двойная сложность: решать задачи не из легких + переводить их с английского. Для обучения он хорош, но у многих возникают трудности с английским.

[image: CodinGame]

3. [CodinGame](https://www.codingame.com/start) - тут, скорее происходит не обучение, а закрепление знаний, но в увлекательном интерактивном формате - написании кода для игры. Всего несколько строк, но не легко! Тут тоже пригодится знание английского, куда же без него!

Вот и все! Удачи!

Comment: Все зависит от того, чему Вы желаете научиться. Мне, например, важно, чтобы код был проще, понятнее и без идиотизма. В отношени двух первых использую cplusplus.com, что кается последнего, то здесь рулит godbolt.org