# Подскажите про функцию такого вида какая тема с++ где узнать что прочитать?

Tags: c++

Функции такого вида какая тема с++ где узнать? что прочитать? вот именно когда указана в скобках < int >.

```
Memory.Read<int>(0x76999A1);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1) Это шаблонный метод.

Comment: Шаблонная функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Шаблонная функция**

Тип данных указывается в "треугольные скобки" отличным примером может послужить сортировка "пузырьком"

```
template < class T > //T это тип передаваемых данных
void bubbleSort (T* a, long size)
{
  long i, j;
  T x;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      for (j = size - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
          if (a[j - 1] > a[j])
            {
              x = a[j - 1];
              a[j - 1] = a[j];
              a[j] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вызывается шаблонные функции так:

```
bubbleSort<int>(arr, 5);
```

Где в треугольные скобки мы передаем тип данных.

Наглядно все показано в готовом коде

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template < class T > //T это тип передаваемых данных
void bubbleSort (T* a, long size)
{
  long i, j;
  T x;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      for (j = size - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
          if (a[j - 1] > a[j])
            {
              x = a[j - 1];
              a[j - 1] = a[j];
              a[j] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
  int arr[5] {1, 3, 2, 5, 4};
  cout << "Non-sorted" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
  }
  bubbleSort<int>(arr, 5); // в треугольных скобках мы передаем тип данных int
    cout << "Sorted" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

В итоге мы получаем такой вывод:

```
Non-sorted
1
3
2
5
4
Sorted
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Будет ли это одним и тем же?
bubbleSort(arr, 5) -> int;

Comment: Нет в треугольные скобки мы передаем тип данных массива в нашем случае `int`

Answer (score 1):

### Это шаблонная функция

Ниже ссылки, где можно почитать про них:

Первые две ссылки - простое введение, третья - статья на википедии (полезно, но чуть посложнее).

Последние две - там много полезной информации, если нужно будет поглубже изучить, очень советую. (на название не обращайте внимание, оно не имеет цели кого-нибудь обидеть ;) )

[Шаблоны функций в С++](http://cppstudio.com/post/5165/)

[Шаблоны классов в С++](http://cppstudio.com/post/5188/)

[Википедия: Шаблоны C++](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_C%2B%2B)

[Программирование шаблонов C++ для идиотов, часть 1](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/an-idiots-guide-to-cpp-templates-part1.html)

[Программирование шаблонов C++ для идиотов, часть 2](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/an-idiots-guide-to-cpp-templates-part2.html)

Comment: Набор ссылок без пояснений не является ответом.

Comment: Добавил пояснение. Вопрос звучал как "где почитать", поэтому в ответе ссылки.