# Чтение байтов/битов из памяти C++

Tags: c++, память

У меня есть файл с int числом в нем. Значит в памяти этот файл занимает 4 байта. Так вот, как мне прочитать эти 4 байта и записать в массив char buffer[4] каждый байт?

Также еще вопрос, как мне прочитать биты этого же файла?

P.S. Простите если это глупый вопрос, только начинаю в c++, знаю как читать и записывать в файл и все.

Comment: Как работать собираетесь? через `FILE*` или `ifstream`?

Comment: @Harry ifstream знаю, а вот FILE* нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: Битами оперируют только если нужно сжатие-расжатие данных без использования библиотек (написание компрессоров-декомпрессоров, кодеков). В реальности такие случаи еденичны (т.к. много готовых библиотек). Второй случай - когда в битах хранят признаки тогда обычными логическими операциями можно проверить признак - но это тогда книги и учебные курсы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если это бинарный файл, то вроде того:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char buf[sizeof(int)];
    ifstream in("filename",ios::binary);
    in.read(buf,sizeof(int));
}
```

Если вы записывали `int` в текстовый файл - типа

```
ofile << i;
```

то что вы хотите прочесть в `buf` - текстовое же представление числа или внутреннее бинарное представление `int`?

**Update**

По результатам беседы в комментариях -

```
ifstream in("filename");
in >> *(int*)buf;
```

Ну, или, если тут будут говорить про strict-aliasing - то

```
ifstream in("filename");
int i;
in >> i;
memcpy(buf,&i,sizeof(int));
```

Comment: текстовое представление я умею читать, а вот "внутреннее бинарное представление int" мне как раз и нужно.

Comment: Но *записано* у вас число как? Бинарно (тогда см. мой ответ) или как текст?

Comment: Число записано как текст.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: вроде работает. Но я не совсем понимаю как он число в каждый байт раскладывает. Т.е. например число 4561 он представляет как:
-47
17
0
0
Не подскажете как мне например понять что -47 в одной байте и 17 в другом - это 4561?

Comment: так например если я запишу число 200 в файл и прочитаю, то первый байт -56, а остальные по нулям. Почему в первом байте не 200 ведь 200<256?

Comment: Потому что `char` может быть и знаковым. Используйте `unsigned char`

Comment: Если использовать беззнаковые `char`ы, то массив будет иметь вид 209 17 0 0 - т.е. младший байт 209, чторой - 17, остальные - 0, т.е. значение 0*256^3+0*256^2+17*256^1+209*256^0 = 17*256+209 = 4561

Comment: Не забывайте про `Big Endian`и `Little Endian`, порядок байт может быть и обратным  (0 0 17 209) (в `Big Endian`)

Answer (score 0):

У меня как-то была подобная задача: сделать цифровую сортировку для чисел. Чтобы не делить на 10, или типа того, я решил использовать байты, а для этого я воспользовался указателями. Для этого вам понадобится два указателя: на char и на int (можно обойтись без последнего). Берете адрес нужного вам числа и присваиваете его указателю на char, для этого используйте static_cast. После этого просто разыменовываете указатель и значение записываете в массив. После этого инкреминируете указатель и проделываете все заново. Количество повторений равно sizeof (int).

Answer (score 0):

Для начала считайте число в переменную типа uint32_t - это 4-байтное число, а дальше вам потребуются побитовые операции. Вот примерный код. Результат записывается в конец. Для наглядности вывожу в хексах:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4

int main()
{
    // считали число в переменную x
    uint32_t x = 255;
    uint8_t buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        buffer[BUF_SIZE - 1 - i] = (x >> (8 * i)) & 0xff;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%02X", buffer[i]);
        if (i != (BUF_SIZE - 1) )
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
00 00 00 FF
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов:

```
using namespace std;   
string i;  // если файл бинарный
int  i;   // если текстовый 
//т.е. тип переменной, куда будем читать, зависит от того, текстовый файл или бинарный 
// остальной код одинаков для обеих случаев
file >> i;
const size_t n = sizeof(int);
bitset<n * 8> b(i);
cout << b;
string s = b.to_string();
for (size_t i = n * 8, k = 1; i >= 8; i -= 8, ++k) {
    bitset<8> bch(s.substr(i - 8, i));
    cout << endl << "Бинарный вид бита номер " << k <<'\t' << bch
         << endl << "числовой вид бита номер " << k <<'\t' << bch.to_ulong();
```