# Изучение c++ технологии

Tags: c++

Какие технологии и основные понятия изучить, чтобы стать крутыми c++ специалистом. Если есть самоучки достигшие высот, делитесь опытом.

Comment: [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: [теоретический минимум для программиста](https://sharpc.livejournal.com/67583.html)

Comment: Внимательность и усидчивость :) остальное придет само..

Comment: И практика, побольше практики... От одного только чтения книг и гайдов скилл не увеличивается.

Comment: перестать ныть и начать писать (читать, анализировать) код.

Comment: Возьмите программу обучения любого стоящего ВУЗа по направлению программирование или разработка ПО и там все будет расписано как вы хотите, а далее дерзайте по-порядку. Также не обходите стороной частные курсы, порой бывают стоящие с хорошими программами. Ну и как всегда, основа это книги и практика в любом ИТ-направлении. Пример самоучки достичшего высот: Илон Маск