# Указатели в с++ и функция

Tags: c++, указатели

Что это означает ?

```
int * function() {
    /* code */
}
```

Comment: Заготовка для написания функции :)

Comment: функция является указателем ? если да на что он указывает?

Comment: @Harry а нельзя просто написать без (*) ?

Comment: Функция **возвращает** указатель. На что? Напишете сами в коде...

Comment: Это функция, возвращающая указатель на `int`.

Comment: Можно без `*`, но тогда она будет возвращать просто `int`.

Comment: Можно какие нибудь простые примеры где функция возвращает указатель? я не до конца понимаю эти указатели  .

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта функция возвращает указатель на `int`, если написать без звёздочки, то она будет возвращать просто `int`.

Разница заключается в том, что [указатель](https://prog-cpp.ru/c-pointers/) это не значение переменной, а ссылка на область памяти.

Простой пример где функция возвращает указатель:

```
int *max (int *a, int *b) {
if (*a > *b)
    return a;
return b;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, *aptr = &a, *bptr = &b;
    *max(aptr, bptr) += 1;
    return 0;
}
```