# ostream::operator<<();

Tags: c++

**вот код:**

```
cout.operator<<("Hello");//он выводит вместо строки какие-то шестнадцетиричные числа 01337BD8P
```

**фактически тот же самый код:**

```
cout << "Hello";//выводит строку 
operator<<(cout,"Hello");//тоже выводит строку
```

В чем разница между записями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basic_ostream для указателей существует несколько перегрузок operator<<.
Часть из этих перегрузок выполнена в качестве функций-членов класса, а часть как внешние функции.

В определении самого класса для указательных типов имеется только перегрузка для параметра типа `void *`

```
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>>
class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<charT, traits> {
public:
    ...
    basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(const void* p);
    ...
};
```

При вызове

```
cout.operator<<("Hello");
```

вызывается именно функция-член класса, а других подходящих вариантов перегрузки нет:
`"Hello"` - массив `char[6]`, который может быть неявно преобразован в `char const *`, который в свою очередь преобразуется в `void const *` поэтому и выводится адрес,  в соответствии с поведением данной перегрузки.

Перегрузки, принимающие `char const *` объявлены как внешние функции:

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&, const char*);
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, traits>&, const char*);
```

В коде

```
operator<<(cout, "Hello");
```

явно вызывается внешняя функция `operator<<`, поэтому функции-члены `basic_ostream` даже не рассматриваются. Естественно, это приводит к выводу строки в соответствии с поведением перегрузки для `char const *`

Код

```
cout << "Hello";
```

приводит к рассмотрению перегрузок `operator<<` объявленных как функции-члены `basic_ostream`, и как внешних функций.
При выборе соответствующих перегрузок, перегрузка с параметром `char const *` оказывается более подходящей, чем остальные, поэтому выбирается соответствующая внешняя операторная функция.

Comment: ГДЕ ТЫ ВСЁ ЭТО У ЗНАЛ ТЫ ЧТО ДЕКСТЕР КАКОЙ-ТО Я НЕ ПОНИМАЮ ГДЕ ВЫ ВСЕ ТАКИЕ ЗНАНИЯ БЕРЕТЕ может книжка какая-то?

Answer (score 5):

Для классов большинство операторов вида `X ■ Y` (включая `<<`) можно перегружать [двумя способами](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators):

- В виде методов (функций-членов класса): `struct A { … operator■(…){…} };`
- В виде свободных (обычных) функций: `struct A {}; int operator■(…, …){…}`

Когда вы пишете `X.operator■(Y)`, компилятор учитывает только те перегрузки `■`, которые сделаны в виде методов.

Когда вы пишете `operator■(X, Y)`, компилятор учитывает только те перегрузки, которые сделаны в виде свободных функций.

Когда вы пишете `X ■ Y`, компилятор учитывает оба варианта перегрузок.

---

**Похоже, что для `std::cout` оператор `<<` для разных типов перегружен разными способами.**

**Для `const char *` (печать строки) он перегружен как свободная функция, а для `const void *` (печать адреса) он перегружен как метод.**

Когда вы пишете `cout << "Hello";`, выбирается перегрузка с параметром `const char *` (свободная функция), потому что она подходит лучше, чем та, что с параметром `const void *` (метод), и чем все остальные варианты.

Когда вы пишете `operator<<(cout,"Hello");`, рассматриваются только перегрузки в виде свободных функций. Из них выбирается та же самая перегрузка, с параметром `const char *`. А вариант с параметром `const void *` не рассматривается вообще, потому что это - метод.

А вот когда вы пишете `cout.operator<<("Hello");`, вариант с `const char *` не рассматривается, и из перегрузок-методов выбирается `const void *`, потому что он подходит лучше других вариантов.

Comment: ты тоже правильно ответил,один вопрос остался:ГДЕ ТЫ ВСЁ ЭТО У ЗНАЛ ТЫ ЧТО ДЕКСТЕР КАКОЙ-ТО Я НЕ ПОНИМАЮ ГДЕ ВЫ ВСЕ ТАКИЕ ЗНАНИЯ БЕРЕТЕ может книжка какая-то?

Comment: @fvBn  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1