# Литература для изучения Си

Tags: c, книги

Посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошие и относительно новые книги по Си. Где информация является свежей и актуальной, и всё написано максимально подробно и понятно.

Comment: Почему-то все вопросы по книгам по языку С закрывают как дубликат этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1 Хотя там нет ни одной книги по С

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Для новичка нет ничего лучше учебников серии Head First. В частности Дэвид и Дон Гриффитс - "[Изучаем программирование на C](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19710905/)".