# Подскажите как избавится от повторений

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, случайные-числа

Как избавиться от повторений в моем коде?.Я так понимаю,необходимо сохранять результаты куда-то(в массив?),а потом сравнивать с новым рандомом,и,если что,вызывать rand заново.Но никак не могу додуматься как это реализовать. Дайте совет или посоветуйте где можно почитать о способе решения моей проблемы. Благодарю за помощь.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int m,k,i,z,j,h=0,kolvo,f,g=0, massiv[g];
    char str1[100];


    srand(time(NULL));

    kolvo=0;
    while (kolvo<15)
    {   
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)               
            {
                m = 97+rand()%3; 
                str1[i]=m;

            }       
            massiv[g]={str1[0],str1[1],str1[2],str1[3],str1[4],str1[5],str1[6],str1[7],str1[8]};            k = 3+rand()%9;
        str1[k]='\0';
        z=0;
        j=0;
        f=0;
        int length_string = strlen(str1);

        //-----------------------------
        {break;}
        if(*(str1)=='a'&&*(str1+1)=='c')            
            for(i=0;i<(length_string);i++)          
            {                                       
                if(*(str1+i)=='c')                  
                    z++;                            
                    if(*(str1+i)=='a')  
                    {
                        if(*(str1+i+1)!='a')        
                        //  if(*(str1+i+2)!='b')
                                j++;
                        f++;
                    }
            }

        //-----------------------------
        if(z==2&&f%2==0&&j==f)
        {
            printf("%s\n",str1);
            kolvo++;

                     g++;
        }
                //-----------------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем сверхзадача вашей программы? Что она должна делать по условию? И что за код - `k = 3+rand()%8; nblu;/mjhng b`??

Comment: В той строчке я не знаю откуда набор символов появился,вероятно на клавиатуру нажал и не заметил(код я исправил). Смысл в том,что бы генерировать и выводить последовательности букв согласно заданому условию. Я все сделал,но последовательности,которые выводятся,иногда повторяются.Этого быть не должно.А как избавится от повторений я просто не могу додуматься

Comment: Что за условия? Может, случайность ни к чему? :)

Comment: Каждая последовательность начинается с ac,в последовательности не больше двух с и в последовательности не может стоять несколько а подряд,только по одной.
Цель создать код,который отбирает и выводит только то,что соответствует условиям и не позволяет повторяться ответам

Comment: Запоминайте, например, в каком-нибудь массиве получаемые последовательности. Когда создаете новую, просматривайте нет ли уже такой и добавляйте, если не нашли

Comment: Ограничения на длину? Буквы могут быть только abc0 (у вас так)? У вас вообще можно просто делать `ac0000..00` и постепенно - как в двоичном числе - строчку нулей менять на 000b, 00b0, 00bb, 0b00... - это все проходит под ваше условие. Такой вариант годится? Если нет, то дайте точное ТЗ...

Comment: Длина от 4 до 9 букв.
Начинается с ас всегда.
а не могут стоять рядом.
с не больше двух шт. в одной последовательности.
Используются только a,b,c.
Работать по задумке должно так:
Рандом создает случайные последовательности. Из них отбираются только соответствующие условиям и выводятся в ответ,пока не наберется 15 правильных последовательностей. Так же должна присутствовать проверка на повторения,что бы при их наличии они устранялись.С последним у меня как раз проблема.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам случайные числа. А проблема у вас еще и в том, что выводятся еще и другие символы - см. https://ideone.com/QiYYsd Без случайных чисел вас устроит решение?

Comment: @Harry Не желательно,так как в задании требуется именно через рандом,да и очень хочется разобраться конкретно с этим вариантом. Думаю то,что там выводятся другие символы,которые в консоли вывода не видно не являются большой проблемой(конкретно в моей ситуации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простейший код, генерирующий 16 неповторяющихся чисел длиной 9, соответствующих вашим правилам:

```
char s[] = "acxbxbxbx";
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        s[2+j*2] = 'a' + ((i >> j)&1);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Если очень тянет на рандомность - ну, добавьте вставку в случайное место второго символа `c`, например...

Ну, а если так уж хотите свой вариант - то @avp вам [уже подсказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931094/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/931111#comment1542363_931094), как...

Вот, например:

```
int main()
{
    set<string> already;
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        string s;
        for(;;)
        {
            s = "ac";
            bool c2 = false;
            for(int l = rand()%5+3; l >= 0; --l)
            {
                string choice = "b";
                if (!c2) choice += 'c';
                if (s.back() != 'a') choice += 'a';
                char c = choice[rand()%choice.length()];
                if (c == 'c') c2 = true;
                s += c;
            }
            if (!already.count(s)) break;
        };
        already.insert(s);
    }

    for(const auto& s: already)
        cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну так я этим изначально и интересовался, хочется сделать так,что бы каждый набор рандомных чисел сохранялся,а потом сверялся с новым рандомом,и в случае совпадения вызывал рандом заново,,и так до того,пока не перестанет повторяться последовательность. Просто не могу понять как это можно сделать...

Comment: Ну смотрите, так сойдет? (дополнил ответ). Простите, но метод мой, разбираться в вашем коде не стал... Главное - проверяю, нет ли уже такой строки - `if (!already.count(s)) break;`, и если нет - добавляю во множество `already.insert(s)`. На выходе - в этом множестве искомые строки...

Comment: Спасибо,воспользуюсь Вашим кодом если не смогу разобраться со своим.Но у меня появилась идея-создать еще один массив такого типа(но я вообще не знаю можно ли так делать?)'massiv[g]={{str1[0]},{str1[1]},{str1[2]},{str1[3]},{str1[4]},{str1[5]},{str1[6]},{str1[7]},{str1[8]}};' т.е. этот массив содержит в себе все рандомные числа,которые в итоге будут выводится. Получается можно будет после каждого рандома создавать такой массив и сравнивать с новым рамнодом,и тем самым избежать повторов.Но есть проблема-я не могу понять какой это тип данных.

Comment: Выдает ошибку "cannot convert  brace enclosed initializer list to *(тип данных) Я изменил свой код,что бы было видно что я сделал

Comment: Либо просит подключить -std=c++11 ,но я не знаю и не могу найти как это сделать

Comment: Знаете, я бы крайне рекомендовал разобраться и указать С++11, а еще лучше - С++17. С++03 уже канул в Лету, образно говоря, в 2019 году работать не с хотя бы С++11 - нонсенс. Какой средой вы пользуетесь? там где-то явно должны быть настройки используемого стандарта...

Comment: Я попытаюсь разобраться. Использую DevC++. Можете сказать,в целом,моя задумка реализуема или это пустая трата времени?

Comment: Все,разобрался и поставил 11 версию.Но,все равно пишет Cannot convert  '<Brace enclosed initializer list>' to 'int' in assigment

Comment: В каком это месте?... На какую строку ругается? Вот - компилируется GCC: https://ideone.com/oIiJzt

Comment: Я про свой код,а не Ваш. А ошибку выдает в massiv[g]={str1[0],str1[1],str1[2],str1[3],str1[4],str1[5],str1[6],str1[7],str1[8]};

Comment: перепробовал все варианты,все равно выдает такую же ошибку. Может подскажете,где можно почитать о моей проблеме?

Comment: В вашем коде не одна ошибка. `massiv[g]` - в С++ размер массива должен быть определен во время компиляции. Присваивание одному элементу целого массива (`massiv[g]={str1[0],...`) бессмысленно; в любом случае массивы не поддерживают присваивание. Можно *инициализировать* массив в объявлении, `int massiv[] = {str1[0],str1[1],...`, но не присваивать. Почитать - ну просто в учебнике по С/С++ - [выбирайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1)...

Comment: Спасибо.Исправил ошибку,но теперь пишет variable size object may not be initialized...

Comment: Извините, но разбираться в каждой ошибке - это уже перебор...