# C++ Создать экземпляр класса, используя заданный размер динамической памяти

Tags: c++

Нужно создать экземпляр класса, используя заданный размер динамической памяти.
Пробовал прописать вот так `Stroka *stroka = new Stroka[10];`, но появляется сообщение "выражение должно иметь тип класса".

Ошибка  C2228   выражение слева от ".vvod" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение

Также как я понимаю, нужно реализовать деструктор

```
~Stroka() // деструктор
{
    delete[] str;
};
```

Код программы ниже:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

class Stroka {
    char str[80];
public:
    Stroka(char*); //конструктор с параметром, ссылка на объект не фиксированного размера
    Stroka(const char*); //конструктор с параметром, ссылка на объект фиксированного размера
    Stroka() {}; //конструктор без параметров
    Stroka(const Stroka&); // Конструктор копирования
    void vvod();
    void vyvod();
}
;

Stroka::Stroka(char *string)
{
    strcpy(str, string);
}

Stroka::Stroka(const Stroka& s)
{
    strcpy(str, s.str);
}

void Stroka::vvod()
{
    cout << "Введите текст:" << endl;
    cin >> str;
}

void Stroka::vyvod()
{
    cout << "Вывод текста на экран:" << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
}

int main(int)
{
    setlocale(0, ""); // установить русскую локацию
    Stroka *s1 = new Stroka[80];
    //Stroka s1;
    s1.vvod();
    s1.vyvod();
}
;
```

Comment: Нужно почитать [Основы с++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 1):

`s1` объявлен как указатель, из-за чего для доступа к полю объекта надо использовать не точку, а стрелку:

```
s1->vvod();
s1->vyvod();
```

С точкой же вы пытаетесь вызвать методы у самого указателя, который ими в принципе не обладает (ими обладает объект *за* указателем).

Компилятор потому и требует «класс, структуру или объединение», что *только в них* могут быть объявлены поля и методы. Сам же указатель слишком примитивен для этого. И сразу же отвечу на потенциальный вопрос: «почему нельзя везде использовать точку, если указатель в принципе не имеет своих полей»: есть ещё умные указатели, являющиеся полноценными классами и имеющие-таки собственные методы помимо указываемого объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Выделяем динамическую память:

```
void * mem = operator new (sizeof(Stroka));
```

Для удобства делаем ссылку на нужный тип:

```
Stroka & str = (* ((Stroka *) mem ));
```

Вызываем конструктор объекта на этом месте:

```
new(mem) Stroka();
```

Потом НЕ забываем вызвать деструктор:

```
str.~Stroka();
```

И НЕ забываем освобождать память:

```
operator delete ( mem ) ;
```

Ваш деструктор НЕ нужен, так как массив str[80] - удаляется вместе с объектом.

```
~Stroka() // деструктор
{
    // delete[] str; не надо
};
```

Comment: А зачем использовать напрямую `operator new` и `operator delete`, и вручную вызывать конструктор и деструктор, вместо того, чтобы просто использовать `new` и `delete`? К тому же, конструктор так не вызывается, нужно использовать placement-new.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Всё забываю синтаксис - мракобесие етот new. Я пытаюсь догадаться условие задачи и прикинул так. Наверное нужно уточнить, что надо?

Answer (score 0):

> @HolyBlackCat Всё забываю синтаксис - мракобесие етот new. Я пытаюсь
>   догадаться условие задачи и прикинул так. Наверное нужно уточнить, что
>   надо?

Нужно сделать вариант конструктора, который создает экземпляр класса, используя заданный размер динамической памяти. 
я только изучаю язык, предположил, что в самом простом варианте это как то делается через new (для меня это просто привычный синтаксис, хотя я прочитал, что в C++ это дурной тон).

Не могу понять как использовать ваш совет. Не могли бы вы выложить внутри моего примера, так было бы в разы понятнее.

У меня получилось вот так:

```
int main(int)
{
    setlocale(0, ""); // установить русскую локацию
    Stroka *s1;
    s1 = new Stroka;
    //Stroka s1;
    s1->vvod();
    s1->vyvod();
    delete s1;
}
```