# Не могу подключить libpng к проекту в VS Community 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, libpng

Никак не могу найти, как правильно установить libpng для VS community 2017. Не смог установить при помощи видео с установкой для VS 2015, так как не совпадают папки, где все проделывалось. Я скачал zlib128 и lpng1618, а дальше не знаю что делать. Я новичок в этом деле, по этому многого не понимаю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: @VTT ну уж точно не дубликат :) Слишком общий, имхо.

Comment: В чем сложности - неясно.. [мануал](http://pididu.com/wordpress/blog/compile-libpng-as-a-static-library-for-windows-with-visual-studio-2010-express/) [рекомендации по сборке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522310/how-to-install-libpng-dev-on-windows)