# При компиляции и исполнении кода иногда выскакивает ошибка

Tags: c++, многопоточность

[image: Компилирую код. В большинстве случаев всё проходит хорошо, но где-то каждый пятый раз с ошибкой. Ошибка всегда одна.]

Суть кода - задаётся число N. 
Создаётся N потоков (помимо основного), которые анализируют поток байтов. 
И каждый поток выдаёт структуру в очередь структур.

И ошибка вылазит только при N > 1.

```
    struct nal_anal 
{
    int number;
    int type;
    int size;
    int M;
};
void analys(uint16_t nal_head, uint16_t numb, int min, int max, queue<nal_anal> &exit){
    nal_anal nal;
    nal.number = numb;
    nal.M = rand() % min + (max - min);
    nal.type = (nal_head & 0x7fff) >> 9;
    nal.size = sizeof(nal_head);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(nal.M));
    exit.emplace(nal);
    cout << "Thread ID: " << this_thread::get_id() << "\t" << nal.number << endl;
    cout << "Обработанный НАЛ юнит:\t" << bitset<16>(nal_head) << "\tНомер \t" << numb << endl;
    }
    int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    srand(time(NULL));

    string path = "video.mkv";
    queue<nal_anal> q;
    int N;
    int MIN = 500, MAX = 500;
    int T = 1;

    cout << "Введите N: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    vector<thread> threads(N);

    ifstream mkv;

    mkv.open(path, fstream::binary);

    if (!mkv.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Not" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Success!" << endl;
        uint32_t numb = 1; //Порядок считать с первого номера
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            unsigned char byte;
            uint16_t nal;
            mkv >> byte;
            nal = static_cast<uint16_t>(byte);
            mkv >> byte;
            nal = (nal << 8) | static_cast<uint16_t>(byte);
            analys(nal, numb, MIN, MAX, ref(q));
            //cout << "Обработанный НАЛ юнит:\t" << bitset<16>(nal) << "\tНомер \t" << numb << endl;
            numb++;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                mkv >> byte;
                nal = static_cast<uint16_t>(byte);
                mkv >> byte;
                nal = (nal << 8) | static_cast<uint16_t>(byte);
                threads[i] = thread(analys, nal, numb, MIN, MAX, ref(q));
                numb++;
            }
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                threads[i].join();
        }



        if (q.empty())
        {
            cout << "empty" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "full" << endl;
        }

        while (!q.empty())
        {
            cout << "Number: \t" << q.front().number << endl;
            cout << "Type: \t" << bitset<6>(q.front().type) << endl;
            cout << "Size: \t" << q.front().size << endl;
            cout << "M: \t" << q.front().M << endl;
            q.pop();
        }
```

В чём может быть проблема? И непостоянство проявления.

[image: Так же разок была другая, но в тех же условиях.]

Comment: Где-то проблемы с памятью. Где конкретно - все равно как угадывать болезнь человека по температуре...

Comment: ...так что код в студию!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Добавил код

Comment: У вас все потоки пишут в `queue<nal_anal> &exit`. Если два потока добавляют элемент одновременно, всё ломается. Надо прикрыть доступ к очереди мьютексом или чем-то подобным.

Comment: Приведен лишь огрызок кода. Что такое `nal_anal`?

Comment: @AnT дополнил. Это структура чисто для передачи результатов (требуемых заданием) в очередь.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ваш ответ про одновременный доступ и использование мьютекса оказался верным\помог. Только комментарий не могу пометить ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код разрушает целостность внутренних структур динамической памяти. Как правило, это вызывается либо записью за пределы выделенной памяти (за пределы массива и т.п.), либо (реже) записью через некорректный указатель, либо попытками "освободить" память, которую вы не выделяли динамически.

"Непостоянство проявления" - нормальное явление в таких случаях. Может быть связано с непостоянством расположения блоков в памяти, а может быть - с каким-то "непостоянством" из вашего кода.

Answer (score 0):

В коде масса проблем:

- файл открывается в бинарном режиме, но чтение из него производится как из текстового
- успешность чтения никогда не проверяется
- бессмысленное создание потоков в цикле
- потоки обращаются к переменной `queue<nal_anal> q;` без синхронизации, что приводит к Неопределенному Поведению

Comment: В обычном режиме вообще не получалось считывать хоть что-либо, поэтому избрал такой путь. Буду рад любой критике\предложениям. Так как число потоков заранее неизвестно, я не придумал ничего лучше, чем создавать их циклом. А синхронизацию как раз добавил, благодаря комментарию выше.

Comment: И в чем же именно заключается бессмысленность создания потоков в цикле?

Comment: @AnT Пересоздание потоков - транжирство ресурсов и в подобной ситуации рекомендуют переиспользовать ранее созданные.

Comment: @LяkushaFujin Могу предложить для начала освоиться с основами языка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-С Чтобы не спотыкаться на базовых вещах. Ну а чтение .mkv подразумевает сначала разбор BML, извлечение из него данных видео потока а затем уже разбор этого потока на единицы пакетирования и NAL юниты

Comment: @VTT согласен, нужно ещё многое узнать. В своё оправдание скажу, что я лишь самоучка и изучал всё по мере необходимости, да и в основном для железа. А тут на собеседовании дали задание (часов через 6-8 его проверять будут). Видимо, я совсем далёк от качественного исполнения. Хотя про разбор видеофайла - делал так, как мне объясняли. Просто получить поток байт, которые потом анализировать в соответствии со стандартом h.265.

Comment: @LяkushaFujin Обычно фраза "для железа" подразумевает экспертный уровень владения языком... А "Просто получить поток байт" из mkv не получится - ведь это хитрый универсальный контейнер для различных медиа потоков и метаинформации к ним. Наверное вам надо было разбирать "сырой" поток .h265 (то бишь не обернутый в контейнер). Такой поток можно получить из энкодера.

Comment: @VTT не знаю где как, но в моём случае "для железа" - работа с микроконтроллерами и и тем. что можно к ним прицепить. Сейчас пытаюсь изучить С++ для софта, так ощущение, что "для железа" вообще ничего почти не требовалось. Либо мне так "повезло".  В задании сказано, что на вход программа получает произвольных h.265\hevc файл. Подумав и погуглив я скачал видео с данной кодировкой. Можно, пожалуйста, подробнее, либо ссылкой, либо формулировкой для поиска про сырой поток и получение из энкодера?

Comment: @LяkushaFujin Затрудняюсь сказать, где в интернете можно найти готовый файл. Обычно все сразу в контейнер запихивают. А [енкодер](http://vtt.to/refined%20x265%20builds) выдает такой сырой поток по-умолчанию. Закодировать можно примерно так `x265.exe --crf 20 --preset fast --sar 1:1 --fps 24000/1001 --input-res 1280x720 --input-depth 8 --input-csp i420 -o output.hevc -` (подразумевается, что видео для кодирования поступает на стандартный вход)

Comment: @VTT Я понимаю, что файл не обязательно будет в mkv контейнере. Просто мне он попался и я работал с ним. Поэтому в основном проекте (код в этом вопросе тестовый из отдельного проекта) я прошу вручную ввести имя\путь к файлу. Подойдёт ли такой способ открытия\чтения для других типов файлов?

Comment: @LяkushaFujin Ну никто так делать не мешает, но по мне было бы проще принимать имя файла в качестве аргумента командной строки, а не вводить его каждый раз вручную.