# Как сохранять данные в файл С++

Tags: c++

Я сделал простой цикл который считает числа и мне надо реализовать сохранения и загрузку данных.
Надо что бы данные как то сохранялись и если я отключил цикл а потом снова запустил он продолжил считать.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{

}
```

Не обязательно простые примеры кидать, можно супер сложные я разберусь.

Comment: Ну делаем что-то типа

    `for (size_t i = loadSavedValue(); i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10000 == 0) saveValue(i);
    }`

Comment: @harry а можно более детально, я думал что это должно работать как то с fstream но я не уверен.

Comment: И еще интересно можно какие то другие данные получать а не числа, например может быть байты.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: В книги точно не будет того что мне нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример - прерываете программу, она при новом запуске будет продолжать работу с последнего сохраненного значения...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long long current_value = 1;
    double current_sum = 0.0;
    {
        ifstream in("data");
        if (in.is_open())
        {
            in >> current_value >> current_sum;
        }
    }
    for(long long i = current_value; ; ++i)
    {
        current_sum += 1.0/i;
        if (i % 10000 == 0)
        {
            ofstream out("data");
            out << i << "  " << current_sum;
            cout << i << "  " << current_sum << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

В каждом конкретном случае надо смотреть, как сохранять и восстанавливать состояние.

В свое время еще под DOS'ом мне попадался код, который тупо сохранял всю память и состояние процессора, но в современных операционках, по-моему, это будет слишком сложным решением...

Comment: пока не могу запустить пишет неизвестные переменные out и  in.is_open
и куда он сохраняет в какой файл?

Comment: Знаете, если вы не понимаете, что надо добавить соответствующие `#include` и не понимаете, где имя файла - то вы, наверное, очень погорячились, говоря "*можно супер сложные я разберусь*"...

Comment: нет нормально, просто нужно время тогда что бы понять

Comment: Кстати, как всегда - хотелось бы выслушать от минусаторов, что **не верно** в моем ответе (другие причины для минуса я не понимаю)...

Comment: у меня получилось запустить код, только пока не понял куда он сохраняет файлы и как должен их загружать что бы продолжать цикл.Цикл вроде начинается с самого начала каждый раз.

Comment: Просто скопируйте, запустите, дайте ему порабтать, прервите... Запустите заново. [Вот как работает](https://i110.fastpic.ru/big/2019/0421/78/60e8859b2fda1dd310bd66b2c3046878.jpg), будучи скомпилированным VC++2017 - я только изменил 10000 на 10000000... Как видите, после прерывания работы она идет с последнего значения.

Comment: ага вроде чет есть, только я пока не понимаю куда он сохраняет данные :)

Comment: @chip, что значит "какой-то дурак"? Я согласен на счет того, что если ты ставишь минус - ты должен указать причину(ы). Но Вы не можете  утверждать, что это сделал именно тот человек, который написал про книги, это во-первых, не **имеете права** кого-либо называть дураком - это во-вторых, и книги бы Вам действительно не мешало почитать - это в-третьих.

Answer (score -2):

Для сохранения в текстовый файл используй:

```c++
int a = 10;
ofstream outf(filename);    //открытие файлового потока записи
outf << a;    //запись в файл

ifstream inf(filename);    //открытие файлового потока считывания
inf >> a;    //считывание инта из файла
```

Comment: А можно пример с циклом полный и куда именно он файл сохраняет и как называться файл будет?

Comment: @chip filename - строка с названием файла, тоесть ты можеш туда записать и адрес файла, если же запишеш только название, как "file.txt", то он сохранится в папку с твоим проектом. Пример с циклом, уже есть выше