# C++ Наследование, Инкапсуляция, Шаблоны

Tags: c++

Есть ли в С++ способ при написании кода ограничить доступ к некоторым функциям класса? Чтобы в каком-нибудь IDE в одном случае в подсказке предлагался, скажем, только f1, а f2 и f3 нельзя бы было использовать. А в другом случае (например, класс шаблонный, и в этом другом случае шаблоном передан другой тип данных) "подсказывались" бы все три метода. Т.е. позволит ли С++ перегрузить конкретный шаблон класса

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    void f1();
    void f2();
    void f3();
}
```

чтобы, например, при написании в коде

```
Test<int>().
```

IDE предлагал в подсказке все три метода, а при

```
Test<double>().
```

открыт был бы только f1? Чтобы f2 и f3 не отображались в подсказке. Возможно, есть способ решения без использования шаблонов?

Comment: Вас это только с точки зрения IDE волнует?

Comment: Язык программы - С++

Comment: Можно попробовать спрятать через `#define` например `#define hide1(a) a` а потом `Type1 hide1(func1)()`  в borland работает, а в студии незнаю.

Comment: А... недочитал... ещё два случая сделать... круто. Да с++ это может сделать, только через `#define` `#ifdef` `#else` `#end` изучайте директивы предпроцессора - и творите чудеса (если ваши со-служивцы не обидятся). Если команда из одного человека - вас - то не вижу в этом смысла. Используя ООП - такие чудеса сделать не получится.

Comment: Что понимается под выражениями "в одном случае" и "при других параметрах"?

Comment: Возможно вам нужно почитать основы с++ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1 Может вам не хватает `friend`-функции/класса. Может вам нужно `template`.

Comment: Не очень хорошо обьяснили что хотите.  Или  поясните получше или приведите пример

Comment: Непонятно, что именно нужно, и вообще - вам нужны шашечки или ехать? в смысле - именно в среде чтоб видно не было, или в программе?...

Comment: NaN, ну и зачем вы откатили мою правку с нормальным названием и метками?

Comment: @V-Mor, вопрос обновлен

Comment: @Kromster
Откатил потому, что подумал, это я что-то стёр по ошибке. И второй вопрос также создал по ошибке: ещё не освоил все возможности сайта. Прошу прощения, вопрос был удалён

Comment: @nick_n_a
 Да, директивы - это хорошо, только они работают при компиляции, а в данном случае необходима удобная работа с классом в процессе написания кода. Friend может подойти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть специализации шаблонов, т.е. в каждой специализации (если нужно) будет свой набор функций.

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    void f1();
    void f2();
    void f3();
}

template <>
class Test<double>
{
public:
    void f1();
}
```

Даст на выходе то, что Вы и просили: только один метод для специализации `double` и три метода для всех других.

Единственная загвоздка здесь — повторение кода функции `f1`. Этого можно избежать вынеся код в какую-нибудь общую сущность и вызывая общую реализацию оттуда. Варианты могут быть разные: наследование от общего класса, свободная функция, некоторый объект, который используется внутри класса и т.д.

Comment: Можно чуть конкретнее насчёт вариантов? общий класс используется на ура, а перегруженный вариант, использующий одно и то же определение метода, что и общий, при использовании этого метода выдаёт unresolved external symbol

Comment: @NaN, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос по конкретной проблеме. В комментариях подобное разбирать сложно, да и людей больше увидит, что у Вас там не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Если я все правильно понял, то

```
//.h
class Class
{
public:
    Type1 func1();
    Type2 func2();
#ifdef USE_FUNC3
    Type3 func3();
#endif

};

//.cpp
#ifdef USE_FUNC3
Type3 Class::func3()
{
    //TODO: place your code here
}
#endif
...
```

Далее следует определять или не определять `USE_FUNC3`. В некоторых **IDE** это можно сделать в настройках проекта, например в qt creator можно установить `DEFINES += USE_FUNC3` в файле .pro.

Другой вариант, это завести файл `project_settings.h` и в нем добавить строчку:

```
//use this to enable func3()
#define USE_FUN3
```

Если что-то не так понял, то поправте, с удовольствием помогу. Доброжелательно советую в дальнейшем формулировать свои вопросы более однозначно.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что привязываться стоит не к ide, а к компилятору. А у всех компилятор есть свои define.