# Массивы, указатели и строки

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

пример кода:

```
char *array = "привет";
cout << array;
```

Почему выводится все слово, а не первая буква?

Comment: Мощный код. Что сделать?

Comment: Ну во-первых этот код невалиден, в С++ нельзя преобразовать строковый литерал к указателю на char. А во-вторых непонятно, почему вы ожидаете, что выведется просто "п"

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что никак не поможет будущим посетительям или вызвать интерес

Comment: Откуда возник такой вопрос? С чего бы это вдруг стала выводиться первая буква вместо всего слова?

Comment: Типа указатель на первый элемент

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну чего так сразу. Смысл вопроса понятен, вопрос логичный. Причесать только надо

Comment: @Razor0109 для справки. char[] и char *  это одно и тоже. Если вам надо первый символ - выводите `*array` (а лучше `array[0]`).

Comment: @pavel, да, смысль вопроса ясен, но... Тогда давайте пропускать вопрос типа  " что такое массив символов"?..  Я  не считаю правильным не открывая учебник пытаться изучать язык в SO

Comment: В языках С и С++ работа с нуль-терминированными строками (С-строками) всегда ведется именно через "указатель на первый элемент" (см. `strlen`, `strcpy` и т.д.). Это, однако, не означает, что все эти функции работают только с "первой буквой". Поэтому не ясно, почему в этом конкретном случае вдруг возник вопрос о "первой букве".

Comment: Окей, пойду перечитаю эту тему. - @pavel

Comment: Оператор `cout` имеет несколько перегрузок: в случае `char*` он выводит символы, пока не встретит нулевой терминатор.

Comment: @AnT - а если в `cout` передать `int*` или любой другой отличный от `char` указатель - почему он не выводит массив чисел и т. п.?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan - _" что такое массив символов"_ - почему нет? Нормальный вопрос. Может, задавший его много лет кодил на функциональных языках, где списки и другие рекурсивные структуры данных. И концепция массива может быть сложна для восприятия.

Comment: Вы не передаете ничего "в `cout`". Вы передаете параметры в перегруженный оператор `<<`. И так реализован стандартный оператор `<<`. Его ручками именно так написали. Для типа `char *` (точнее `const char *`) реализована отдельная версия `<<`, которая выводит С-строку. С-строка - это не просто "массив символов", а несколько больше. А вот для типа `int *` не написали отдельного оператора. Можете сами его написать, если хотите.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, здравствуйте, специально зарегистрировался, чтобы оставить вам ответ на комментарий, но такой возможности у меня, пока, нет, поэтому просто оставляю ответ к этому посту. Сейчас ищу как можно больше информации по данной теме (массивы указателей на строки). Если бы вы могли предоставить мне ссылки или название книг, где я могу почитать подробнее об этой теме, я был бы очень признателен вам. Заранее спасибо. Надеюсь, что вы увидите данный комментарий.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/235436

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, почему вы ожидали получить один символ.

Ведь если бы указатель был не на `char`, а, скажем, на `int`, то вы получили бы не этот `int`, а численное значение самого указателя (в шестнадцатеричном виде):

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};
int *ptr = &array[0];
std::cout << ptr << '\n'; // `0x7ffdc12431dc`, а не `1`
```

<sup>(Вроде бы в стандарте не написано, как точно должны выводиться указатели, но на всех компиляторах, которые я видел, они выводятся как шестнадцатеричные числа.)</sup>

Для `cout` указатели на `char` - это особый случай. `cout` считает их указателями на начало строк, и выводит как строки.