# C++ - Почему допускается такой вызов, если он не соответствует синтаксису?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, синтаксис

Есть определение типа:

```
void foo() {
    /* ... */
}
```

Почему можно вызвать `foo;`, то есть без скобок, когда правильно именно `foo();`?

Мой компилятор не запрещает такой вызов, а просто выводит *warning*.

Я не могу понять, это альтернативный метод вызова, или раньше планировалось это как-то применять, но потом передумали?

Comment: Возможно, такой вопрос, и даже *неоднократно*, уже задавали. Но я не смог найти, или подобрать формулировку для поиска.

Comment: для проверки "на всех компиляторах" https://godbolt.org/z/ikMLdN

Comment: Drawn Raccoon огромное спасибо, это еще asm код приводит. Такого в online я еще не находил...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что это **не вызов**.

Это просто выражение, которое имеет в качестве значения указатель на функцию. Примерно как если бы вы написали

```
int x = 5;

x; 5;
```

Это у вас никаких возражений не вызывает? Просто особого смысла нет... и не более того.

Comment: То есть, если я пишу foo; то у меня не выполняется код из foo?

Comment: А вы что, сразу бросились спрашивать и даже не проверили?! 8-/ Конечно, нет.

Comment: Ну тогда зачем оно нужно? Вот в чем смысл вопроса? То есть, компилятор знает что такое `foo`, и разрешает `foo;` Зачем?

Comment: Подождите, ну указатель то понятно, но его нужно обрабатывать же, то есть, одно дело когда это где-то используется, а другое просто`foo;`

Comment: > А вы что, сразу бросились спрашивать и даже не проверили У меня же нет возможности проверить это на всех компиляторах...

Comment: Компилятор разрешает выражения без присваивания? Например, `z = bar(x);` и просто `bar(x)`? Тогда почему бы не разрешить просто `foo;`, если разрешено `f = foo;`? К чему плодить лишние сущности?...

Comment: Хорошо, а сточки зрения asm, куда перейдет этот `foo;` Это **NOP**?

Comment: А проверить - да хоть на одном-единственном. Вот, например - https://ideone.com/onLAof

Comment: **Harry**, у меня почти такой же код. Я проверил что вызова нет, но вот зачем 'foo;' в чистом виде, ладно любое использование, а то просто оператор.

Comment: А вот это уже - ассемблерный код - зависит от конкретной реализации. Думаю, что его просто не будет вообще, ни в какой инструкции.

Comment: Так а все же, если `foo;` без использования, он заменяется на NOP или опускается?

Comment: Уже ответили...

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос удаляю, мне правда стыдно спрашивать, но я хочу разобрать все, что я не понимаю, и хорошо если бы был форум с такой темой, типа вопросы нубов и т. д. Но форумы, которые я читаю, предлагают создавать новую тему...

Comment: **Harry**, спасибо еще раз...

Comment: **Harry**, я хотел задать вопрос в чате, чтобы не засорять RU StackOverflow, но не хватает репутации ( Может посоветуете литературу, что читать начинающему? Знаю что есть много книг, но говорят стандарт меняется, поэтому хочется понимать основы, но чтобы это не было устаревшим.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1

Comment: Спасибо, выписал несколько авторов: Бьерн Страуструп, Брюс Эккель, Стенли Липпман из серии для начинающих. Понять бы еще, Какая из 5-ти книг больше на новичка. Попробую разобраться, заодно может добавлю комментарий в ту тему ;) откуда вынес больше пользы...

Comment: Ну, если совсем уж с нуля - то скорее Дэвис или Рао...

Comment: Хорошо, приму Ваш совет, знаний у меня и правда почти 0...