# Работа с vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Задание:
В контейнере типа vector хранятся елки(поля: высота, цена).Необходимо разработать программу для :
1.  Поиск минимального значения(по высоте, цене)
2.  Поиск максимального значения
3.  Сортировка данных по убыванию
4.  Сортировка данных по возрастанию
5.  Увеличение значений в контейнере на заданную константу
6.  Уменьшение значений в контейнере на заданную константу
7.  Удаление элементов из контейнера равных искомому значению

```
class tree
{
private:
    float height;
    float price;
public:
    tree(float height, float price) : height(height), price(price){}

    float getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    float getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<tree> _tree;
    vector<tree>::iterator it;
    it = _tree.begin();

    float height;
    float price;

    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");

        cout << "MENU" << endl << endl;
        cout << "1 - add tree" << endl;
        cout << "2 - find the minimum value" << endl;
        cout << "3 - find the maximum value" << endl;
        cout << "4 - sort data in descending order" << endl;
        cout << "5 - sort data in ascending order" << endl;
        cout << "6 - increase the values in the container by a given constant" << endl;
        cout << "7 - decrease values in the container by a given constant" << endl;
        cout << "8 - removing items from the container equal to the desired value" << endl;
        cout << "9 - exit" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter: ";
        int menu;
        cin >> menu;

        switch (menu)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                system("cls");

                cout << "Enter height: ";
                cin >> height;
                cout << "Enter price: ";
                cin >> price;
                tree t(height,price);
                _tree.push_back(t);

                Sleep(500 * 1);
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                system("cls");



                Sleep(1000 * 1);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

Как мне через vector достучаться к полям класса, что бы с ними работать ?

Comment: Через интерфейс `tree`. Типа `tree_[i].getPrice()`. В чем проблема? А все сортировки - просто пишете свой компаратор..

Comment: А вам компилятор не сообщает об ошибке создания экземпляра класса с одним аргументом в конструкторе?

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам некоторые подсказки:

```
class tree
{
private:
    float height;
    float price;
public:
    tree(float height, float price) : height(height), price(price){}

    float getHeight() const
    {
        return height;
    }

    float getPrice() const
    {
        return price;
    }

    void setPrice(float newPrice)
    {
        price = newPrice;
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<tree> trees;

    // Итератор на елку с наименьшей ценой
    auto min_price = min_element(trees.begin(),trees.end(),
                                 [](const tree& a, const tree& b)
                                 {
                                     return a.getPrice() < b.getPrice();
                                 });

    // Сортировка елок по высоте
    sort(trees.begin(),trees.end(),
         [](const tree& a, const tree& b)
         {
             return a.getHeight() < b.getHeight();
         });

    // Увеличение цен в контейнере в 2 раза
    for_each(trees.begin(),trees.end(),[](tree&a) { a.setPrice(a.getPrice()*2); });

    // или

    for(auto& t: trees) t.setPrice(t.getPrice()*2);

}
```

Из советов: не пренебрегайте `const`! и не используйте подчерк первым символом - такие имена зарезервированы С++ для внутренних целей (на самом деле правила более точные, чем просто начинающиеся с подчерка, но проще приобрести привычку просто не использовать первым символом подчерк вообще).

Comment: Как оказалось все намного проще, я циклом с временными переменными делал задания. У меня к вам вопрос. К примеру возьмем этот участок кода ```C++  auto min_price = min_element(trees.begin(),trees.end(),
                                 [](const tree& a, const tree& b)
                                 {
                                     return a.getPrice() < b.getPrice();
                                 });``` Как результат вывести в консоль ? Наименьшую цену за елку )

Comment: `cout << min_price->getPrice();`

Comment: Блин, а можете объяснить немного данный код, я вроде его понимаю, но не совсем. min_price - это наша переменная. min_element - Это функция ? Или что это ? И получается наша переменная min_price это указатель ? я понимю что такое tree.begin() это начало, tress.end() конец. Что дальше идет, вообще не понимаю ((( Может есть где-то статья, что бы разобрать этот код ? Или может вы сможете объяснить ?)

Comment: [`min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) - функция стандартной библиотеки, которая ищет минимальный элемент в диапазоне. Возвращает **итератор** (который, грубо говоря, можно рассматривать как указатель, хотя это и не он в общем случае). Почитать - ну, в принципе, [любой учебник по современному С++ и его библиотеке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1).

Comment: Далее я использую опять же стандартные алгоритмы [`sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) и [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: ```auto maxPrice = max_element(trees.begin(), trees.end(), [](tree& a, tree& b)
     {
      return a.getPrice() > b.getPrice();
     });

    cout << "Max price: " << maxPrice->getPrice() << endl;```Я так понимаю, с max_element должен так же работать ? Почему мне выдает наименьшее число ?

Comment: Потому что вы изменили компаратор на обратный. Или оставьте в компараторе знак `<`, или, если в нем будет знак `>` - то ищите минимальный элемент. Компаратор обеспечивает проверку пользовательского отношения меньше (например, если 5 меньше 2, а 2 меньше 1 - то минимальный элемент в обычной арифметике окажется наибольшим :))

Comment: Хотел сказать вам, огромное спасибо, очень помогли. Очень много нового узнал и по чуть чуть начал разбираться с этим всем. У меня остался последний вопрос, а как отсортировать не по возрастанию, а по убиванию ? ) Я пробывал менять < >, еще разные способы, но не смог, не подскажите ?)

Comment: А вот тут как раз меняете компаратор - делаете свое пользовательское отношение "меньше" реальным отношением "больше" - в компараторе в `sort` меняйте `<` на `>`...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103161/discussion-between-titov-and-harry).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант работы с vector'м объектов какого-либо класса (доступ к методам элемента/объекта vector'а):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Tree
{
private:
    float mHeight;
    float mPrice;
public:
    Tree(float height, float price)
    : mHeight(height), mPrice(price){}

    float getHeight()
    {
        return mHeight;
    }

    float getPrice()
    {
        return mPrice;
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::vector<Tree> vecTree = {
        Tree(1.55, 1450.0),
        Tree(1.65, 1670.0),
        Tree(1.07, 989.9)
    };


    std::cout << "All vector of trees: " << std::endl;
    for(auto iter=vecTree.begin(); iter!=vecTree.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << "Tree( " << iter->getHeight() << ", " << iter->getPrice() << " );" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```