# Посоветуйте, с чего начать изучать отрасль программирования

Tags: c++

Я, учусь на 1 курсе колледжа на факультете компьютерной инженерии. Самостоятельно пытаюсь изучать с++ каждый день, тратя 2-4 часа в сутки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что изучать вместе с с++, как действовать, что-бы стать хорошим программистом. Мне нравиться писать код, но посмотрев пару статей и обьем информации что нужно учить голова кругом. В каком направлении дальше двигаться(хотел бы что-то с защитой по, но смотрю на сложность всего этого, и мне страшно) и что учить. Буду благодарен любой информации, любому ответу. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: После того, как поняли основы языка, не учитесь "чтобы стать хорошим программистом". Учитесь чтобы сделать конкретную, полезную на практике программу. Начните делать небольшую игру (или что-то другое, смотря что вам интересно), и на ходу изучайте все, что понадобится. Успешно сделали - молодец, начинайте следующую. Не осилили? Оцените, что пошло не так, и начинайте следующую.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал начать с ОС - возьмите Линукс посмотрите как работает, как написан и тд. Разберитесь в Си потом уже любой язык будет проще. Отрасли пока не смотрите. Разберитесь как вообще работает ОС драйвера, стек tcp, tls и тд. А там уже сами поймёте что хотите. Для начала сделайте все пазлы на codingames. Потом будет осознание куда идти. Посмотрите в сторону С# почитайте что на нем делают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем смотри,расклад такой.Сразу могу сказать,не нужно бросаться на теорию и заучивать ее наизусть,самый лучший способ изучить какую-либо тему,это придумать себе  простенький проект,например для начала тебе подойдет что-то вроде:

"Создайте динамический массив из N элементов(N вводит пользователь).Найдите среди элементов максимум и удалите в массиве последний элемент,если об этом попросит пользователь.Во время размышления над этим проектом ты изучишь простенький алгоритм,также познакомишься с указателями,динамической памятью(одни из основных тем из С++)

Если ты хочешь все-таки заниматься в дальнейшем С++,то тебе понадобится матанчик(Мат анализ,дискретная математика,линейная алгебра).Есть прекрасная книга "Дискретная математика для программиста"Этого тебе хватит по горло.

Большим плюсом будет изучить Базы Данных,**(Алгоритмы и структуры данных-Важно!!)** и конечно же CS(базовые знания Пк,сетей и тд)

Не стоит забывать про Английский,очень много информации именно на нем!Также сделай акцент!

В заключение хочу сказать,коль уж ты новичок  и тебе нравится кодить,то посмотри другие технологии и Языки Программирования(Например посмотри Web Разработку,Java-Разработку и т.д)В интернете кучу информации,просто найди свое)Удачи тебе,друг!

Comment: Скрытая реклама вэба?

Comment: @Maggot Аахаха,вам показалось:)