# Решено. Не определяется ранее объявленная локальная переменная (C++)

Tags: c++, переменные, visual-studio-2019

Делаю простой калькулятор на C++, который будет складывать числа, который ввод пользователь.
При компиляции программы в главном файле вызываются ошибки:
"x: необъявленный идентификатор", "y: необъявленный идентификатор"

Вот код:

Главный файл (Calculator.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "enterx.h"
#include "entery.h"
#include "add.h"

int main()
{


   std::cout << "The sum of your numbers is " << add(x, y) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Первое слагаемое (X) (enterx.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

int enterx(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Enter X" << std::endl;
    x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "X = " << x << std::endl;

    return x;
}
```

enterx.h :

```
#ifndef ENTERX_H
#define ENTERX_H

int enterx(int x);

#endif
```

Со вторым слагаемым тоже самое, но x заменен на y

Код на складывание (add.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>

int add
{
#include "enterx.h"
#include "entery.h"

    return x + y;
}
```

add.h :

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int a, int b)

#endif
```

Comment: "Делаю простой калькулятор на C++" - не такой уж он, как выясняется, простой

Comment: я имел ввиду простой калькулятор в плане задумки, который только складывает, а так-то язык далеко не простой:)

Comment: Включение файлов посреди функции - просто издевательство, откровенно говоря...

Answer (score 3):

Нет-нет, что Вы, это не так работает... `#include` это директива препроцессора. Простыми словами это значит, что на момент исполнения программы этой фигни с решоткой не будет существовать. Перед тем как начать компилировать Вашу программу, специальная штуковина посмотрит на такие штуковины и изменит Ваш код. В данной ситуации вместо этой штуковины будут все остальные штуковины из файла. То есть он как будто возьмет код оттуда и вставит вместо этой штуковины. Как то так...

```cpp
int add(int a, int b)
{
#include "enterx.h"
#include "entery.h"

    return x + y;
}
```

Давайте взглягем не Вашу программу так, будто вы хотите ее *скомпилировать*... Нет, ***испольнить***!

```cpp
int main()
{
   std::cout << "The sum of your numbers is " << add(x, y) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Ничего необычного, мы как всегда начинаем исполнение любой программы с этой проклятой функции, *идем дальше...*

```cpp
int main()
{
```

Ого, надо разобрать по подробней...

```cpp
std::cout << "The sum of your numbers is " << add(x, y) << std::endl;
```

- `std::cout` - Да, знаем мы таких, `iostream` что-то про него говорил
- `<<` - Ну тут понятно
- `"The sum of your numbers is "` - Строка как строка...
- `add(x, y)` - А вот тут давайте еще подробней...

  - `add` - Была такая, подключалась в `add.h`
  - `x, y` - Вот про этих пасажиров я ничего не знаю... С меня хватит!

Примерно так же работает Ваш компилятор. Где вы объявили `x` и `y`? Правильно, нигде.

---

Рабочий пример:

```
#include <iostream>

int enter(char c)
{
    std::cout << "Enter " << c << std::endl;
    int x;

    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << c << " = " << x << std::endl;

    return x;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    int x = enter('X');
    int y = enter('Y');

    std::cout << "The sum of your numbers is " << add(x, y) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Давайте разберемся какого черта:

Ну ладно, это мы уже видели

```cpp
int main()
{
```

```cpp
int x = enter('X');
```

- Создадим переменную типа `int` с именем `x` и сразу же зададим ей значение...
- Из функции `enter`... еще и передадим туда 'X'... Ну ладно...

Вроде бы все складывается, функция ждет, чтобы ей передали символ `c`, как мы знаем передали туда 'X'

```cpp
int enter(char c)
{
```

Окей, ничего странного, выводим "Enter " и значение c(в нашем случае 'X')

```cpp
std::cout << "Enter " << c << std::endl;
```

Создадим числовую переменную `x`, окей

```cpp
int x;
```

Подождем пока юзер чет нам сбросит и попробуем записать это в x.

```cpp
std::cin >> x;
```

Покажем чего мы там наполучали от него

```cpp
std::cout << c << " = " << x << std::endl;
```

И соответственно вернем результат.

```cpp
return x;
```

И так, добро пожаловать в прошлое, пройдя целый путь по огромной функции `enter` мы смогли ее выполнить и узнали, что она вернет нам значение, которое отправит пользователь, теперь в переменной x будет то самое значение...

```cpp
int x = enter('X');
```

- *Создадим переменную типа* `int` *с именем*... Стоп, это уже было, просто параметр поменялся. Произойдет все тоже самое, что и в прошлой строчке, просто во время ввода пользователя он увидит на экране букву `Y` вместо `X` и результат вернется в переменную `y`

```cpp
int y = enter('Y');
```

В прошлый раз мы психонули именно на этой строчке, в этот раз у нас уже существуют и `x` и `y`, так что можем ее выполнить и увидеть то, что вы хотели увидеть в самом начале.

```cpp
std::cout << "The sum of your numbers is " << add(x, y) << std::endl;
```

Просто не будет завершать программу, пока пользователь не нажмет любую кнопку, чтобы консоль/терминал не закрывались сразу, а вы могли насладиться своей программой. Вы сможете любоваться ей пока продумываете свой план по продаже Вашей программы в AppStore, GooglePlay, Steam и т.д. Мелочь, а приятно :)

```cpp
system("pause");
```

Comment: *add - Была такая, подключалась в add.h* - не-а, точки-то с запятой там нет... так что выполнять начинаем `int add(int x, int y) int main() {`

Comment: @Harry Ага, я даже не смотрел в заголовки)

Comment: Спасибо, но пока это слишком сложно для меня, только изучаю язык. А калькулятор хотел сделать для закрепления изученного

Comment: @МаратКамчатский По каким-то не тем учебникам учите, похоже... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342

Answer (score 0):

Выполним ваши подстановки файлов...

**CALCULATOR.CPP**

```
int enterx(int x);
int entery(int y);
int add(int a, int b)
int main()
{
   std::cout << "The sum of your numbers is " << add(x, y) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**ADD.CPP**

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
int enterx(int x);
int entery(int y);
    return x + y;
}
```

**ENTERX.CPP**

```
int enterx(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Enter X" << std::endl;
    x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "X = " << x << std::endl;
    return x;
}
```

А теперь посмотрите сами и скажите - такой код можно скомпилировать?

Еще куда ни шло компилируем `enterx.cpp`, но `add.cpp`? Где не объявлены никакие переменные `x` или `y`, но вы их суммируете? Или `calculator.cpp`? В котором вообще непонятно что...

Comment: насчет add.cpp я пытался эксперементировать, но забыл вернуть в работоспособное состояние.