# Как должна выглядеть хорошая архитектура приложения на C++?

Tags: c++, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучил GOF и GRASP паттерны, хорошо помню каждый из них и смогу без проблем сделать пример кода с одним из паттернов без подсказок.
Но когда дело доходит до реальных проектов, максимум что вспоминается - паттерн одиночка(который, к слову, я так понимаю использую очень часто, и зря, а все потому что не понимаю как сделать иначе лучше).
Спустя несколько тысяч строк кода начинаю понимать, что допускаю много ошибок в архитектуре программы и можно было сделать лучше, даже используя те же паттерны проектирования.
Где то не понимаю, стоит ли создавать класс Application, который будет хранить объекты классов Gui, Network, или лучше Gui и Network сделать одиночками.
Я понимаю, что все должно приходить с опытом, но спустя месяца я понимаю, что я как не понимал как это делать правильно - так и не понял.
Есть какие нибудь хорошие книги, которые помогут лучше понять архитектуру программ?
Или примеры проектов с открытым исходным кодом с грамотной архитектурой, что бы понимать как должна выглядеть хорошая архитектура приложения?

Comment: Это слишком общий вопрос ..

Comment: В хорошей архитектуре код покрыт модульными тестами (во всяком случае, должна быть возможность сделать это). Чтобы код можно было покрыть тестами, он должен быть слабо связан. Чтобы появилась слабая связанность, нужно реализовать инъекцию зависимостей.

Comment: этот вопрос похож на "Как должна выглядеть хорошо организованная фирма? " Какая фирма, по каким критериям, под чьим представлением?... Как определяется насколько хорошо организовано производство или строительство какого то комплекса?  Как вы сами организовали бы?.. Меньше лишних затрат и операций, правильная связь между разными звеньями(бригадами), тщательный выбор этих бригад и их функций, и т.д. и т.п. В итоге вы должны обеспечить требования заказчиков и клиентов.Точно также и в программировании. Много опыта,  и знаний и немного фантазии,..

Comment: Думаю ваша ошибка в том, что вы стараетесь больше вспоминать, чем понимать....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По архитектуре и культуре программирования именно на C++ книг довольно много, например:

Джефф Элджер - "C++" - выделяется тем, что учит не сколько языку, сколько культуре программирования на нем.

Ален И. Голуб - "ВЕРЕВКА ДОСТАТОЧНОЙ ДЛИНЫ,ЧТОБЫ ВЫСТРЕЛИТЬ СЕБЕ В НОГУ Правила программирования на С и С++"

*Обе книги выделяются тем, что сейчас модно называть "токсичностью". Однако стоит понимать, что разработка - это не посиделки со смуззи в баре, а серьезная работа, а ваша ошибка может [убить кого-то](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25).*

Также замечу, что некоторые советы по оптимизации программ, приведенные в этих книгах, более не актуальны, либо, подлежат обсуждению. Процессоры и компиляторы сильно поумнели.

Рекомендую [большой список литературы от сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1)