# Новичок в программировании. Можете посоветовать пособия?

Tags: c++

Очень хочу научиться программированию на c++ (до этого учил только Pascal на уроках информатики в школе), можете ли посоветовать пособия или учебники для изучения возможностей языка? Язык изучаю с целью понять как работают программы ОС и движки игр. Также встречаю много советов в интернете начинать с других языков, но не понимаю почему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: Много советов начинать с других языков, так как в С/C++ очень высокий порог вхождения. С каким-нибудь питоном уже через неделю можно будет на превдокоде фигачить что-то работающее, а с С/C++ люди и через пять лет теряются с подключением библиотек. Начинайте с Ada

Comment: Начните просто с Си (и да, ОС пишут в основном на нем). Для начала прочтите [K&R](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)) (впрочем, для изучения собственно **языка**, на ней можно и остановиться)