# Для чего нужен Символ * перед именем функции?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

```
const double * f1(const double ar[], int n);
const double * f2(const double * ar, int n);
const double * f3(const double [], int);
const double * f4(const double *, int);
```

Добрый день, изучаю указатели на функции. Все эти функции принимают массив и его длину. arr представляет адрес массива. К параметрам вопросов нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста:

- для чего нужна `*` перед `f1, f2, f3, f4`.
- `*` может встречаться только в прототипах или в определении функции тоже?
- `*(указатель)` указывает на возвращаемый тип функции?

Где можно почитать конкретно про такие случаи? Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: В старом стиле перед функцией указывается тип возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Это значит, что функция возвращает указатель

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все эти функции возвращают указатели на массивы вещественных чисел. Как Вы, наверное, знаете (или можете узнать [отсюда](http://cppstudio.com/post/423/)) указатель в `С++` это такой тип данных, который хранит **адрес в памяти**, а указатель на массив — указывает туда, где хранится его первый элемент или, правильнее сказать хранит в себе адрес первого элемента массива. (Первый это тот, у которого индекс = 0).

Если звездочку в прототипе не указывать, то функция будет возвращать не адрес по которому хранится `double`, а само значение `double`. Чем они отличаются, думаю понятно, но если нет, то можно [почитать лекцию](http://algcourse.cs.msu.su/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Lect_08.pdf). Правда там `СИ`, а не `С++`

Про указатели на функции: Указатели на функции указывают на (хранят в себе адрес) функций. То есть когда мы вызываем какую-то функцию, программа переходит ее **по адресу** и начинает ее выполнять.

Объявить указатель на функцию можно так:

```
int foo (){
return 7;
} // сама функция

int main(){
int (*fooPtr ()) = foo; // указатель на foo
}
```

Почитать про указатели на функции можно [тут](https://ravesli.com/urok-104-ukazateli-na-funktsii/)

Answer (score 2):

Функция описывается так:

```
возвращаемый_тип имя_функции([тип1 аргумент1 [, тип2 fргумент2] ...)
```

Так что в

```
const double * f2(const double * ar, int n);
```

`const double *` - возвращаемый тип, `f2` - имя функции, `const double *` - тип первого аргумента `ar`, `int` - тип второго аргумента `n`.

Так понятнее?

На второй вопрос - "прототип" и определение должны совпадать (кроме, разве что, имен аргументов), так что `*` нужна точно так же, чтобы указывать возвращаемый тип.

Почитать обо все этом можно в [учебниках по C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342).

P.S. К вашему

> изучаю указатели на функции

Указатель на функцию данного типа будет иметь вид

```
const double * (* func_ptr)(const double *, int);
```