# C. Таблица строк

Tags: c++, c

Недавно читал книженцию одну. "Справочник по языку С"(автор Шилдт) называется. Так вот: там написано про "таблицу строк".
https://cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/05/0507.html
Вот тут последний абзац.
Искал информацию по ней в других источниках и не нашел.
Не подскажите, как это вообще работает?
Ах да, код:

```
char *p = "тестовая строка";//где выделяется память под эту строку?
//Ведь, кроме строк, с массивами других типов такое не пройдет.
```

Comment: А где выделяется память под код программы? :) Теоретически, зависит от используемой платформы. Где-то в образе программы, который загружается в оперативную память для выполнения. Это не самый строгий ответ, но зато должен быть понятным... И, кстати, вполне пройдет и с другими массивами - например, глобальный массив `int a[] = {1,2,3,4}` - будет он точно так же сразу в образе программы.

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот я хотел именно с указателем. Типа int* p ={1,2,3,4};

Comment: Без вопросов :) Допишите `int * p = a;`...

Comment: Уже понял. Спасибо еще раз.)))

Answer (score 1):

По приведённой в вопросе ссылке описываются некоторые технические детали в работе компиляторов. С точки зрения стандарта языка расклад таков.

Все строковые литералы — это массивы со статическим классом памяти из `n` элементов, где `n` включает завершающий нулевой символ. Статический класс памяти означает, что массив существует на протяжении всего времени работы программы. Т.е. указатель на элемент строкового литерала можно, например, безопасно вернуть из функции.

```cpp
const char* f1()
{
    char arr[5] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};

    //Возвращаем указатель на элемент локального массива.
    //Массив перестаёт существовать при выходе из функции
    //Поведение программы не определено.
    return arr;
}

const char* f2()
{
    //OK. "test" - статический массив, и он не будет уничтожен при выходе из функции
    return "test";
}
```

Так как строковый литерал есть массив, то он может быть неявно приведён к указателю на свой первый элемент.

```cpp
int  arr_int[]  = {48, 49, 50, 51, 0};

//OK. p_int указывает на первый элемент массива arr_int.
int* p_int = arr_int;

//OK p_char указывает на первый элемент массива "0123".
const char* p_char = "0123";
```

Тип элементов строкового литерала в языке C++ определяется следующим образом:

- Нет префикса — `const char`,
- Префикс `u8` — `const char8_t`,
- Префикс `u` — `const char16_t`,
- Префикс `U` — `const char32_t`,
- Префикс `L` — `const wchar_t`,

В языке C аналогично, но

- типы не содержат `const`-квалификатора,
- тип элементов литералов с префиксом `u8` — `char` (в C11 так, возможно в последних версиях черновиков стандарта изменено),
- типы `char16_t` и `char32_t` определены в заголовочном файле `uchar.h` и есть псевдонимы для типов `uint_least16_t` и `uint_least32_t` соответственно.
- тип `wchar_t` определён в заголовочном файле `stddef.h` и есть псевдоним для некоторого другого целочисленного типа.

И в C, и в C++ попытка изменения строкового литерала приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Важное свойство строковых литералов — они могут перекрываться в памяти.

```cpp
char arr1[] = {1, 2, 3};
char arr2[] = {1, 2, 3};

//Гарантированно false;
&arr1[0] == &arr2[0];

//Может быть как true, так и false.
&"test"[0] == &"test"[0];
```

---

В последнем примере можно было бы сравнить адреса первых элементов массивов `arr1` и `arr2` так:

```cpp
arr1 == arr2
```

Это корректный код. Массивы неявно приводятся к указателям на свои первые элементы, и происходит сравнение указателей. Однако, в C++20 возможность сравнивать два операнда с типом массив признана устаревшей (deprecated), и, вероятно, будет удалена в будущих версиях стандарта языка.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как всегда, ответ на вопрос порождает 2 вопроса.

Comment: 1-й: В каком случае литералы могут пересекаться? Если один является префиксом другого(было бы логично экономить память) или как-то иначе?

Comment: 2-й вопрос: Можете посоветовать какую-нибудь хорошую книгу по С. Просто хотелось бы как-то глубоко копнуть это все дело и разбираться хорошо, а на первом курсе нам даже близко такого не дают(

Comment: @БогданЗараник 1) Литералы могут перекрываться, если это возможно :) Например, `"test"` и `"st"`. Литерал `"st"` по сути часть `"test"`, поэтому компилятор в целях экономии памяти может хранить только `"test"`, а там, где нужен `"st"` будет просто подставлять нужный кусочек большего литерала. С другой стороны `"te"` и `"test"` перекрываться не должны. Ведь они различаются в третьем символе (у `"te"` третий символ — это `\0`). Но опять же, если компилятор сможет доказать, что обращения к третьему символу в `"te"` никогда не произойдёт, то не факт, что адрес `"te"` не совпадёт с адресом `"test"`

Comment: [Пример](https://ideone.com/hwgH8G). 2) Книгу на самом-то деле сложно посоветовать. Какую бы вы не выбрали, наверняка найдутся какие-нибудь слабо освещённые особенности языка. Посмотрите вопрос: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263)

Answer (score 0):

Строки как часть программы храняться в самом коде, и их невозможно менять, так как код программы защищён от копирования. Но если в какой-нибудь функции создать копию данной строки, то эту копию можно модифицировать.

```
char strarr [ ] = "abc" ;
char const * strptr = "def" ;
void func(void){
    char locstrarr [ ] = "ghi" ;
    char const * locstrptr = "jkl" ;
}
```

Переменная `strarr` - это массив букв, в который при старте программы записываются **четыре** буквы : `'a'` , `'b'` , `'c'` и конец строки `'\00'` . Данный массив **можно** менять. Память для этой строки выделяется при старте программы. А если внутри функции, то каждый раз в стеке.

Переменная `strptr` - это указатель на массив константных букв. Эти буквы модифицировать нельзя, так как указатель указывает на одну из записей **таблицы** строк. И эта таблица как часть программы защищена от изменений. Выделяется память только для указателя (8 байт) в выделенном для этого свободном участке памяти или в стеке (если внутри функции).