# Semantic issue указатель на функцию

Tags: c++, функции, классы, указатели

Разбираюсь с указателем на функцию и возникли вопросы.

1. Почему компилятор ругается

   ```
   A();
   ~A();

   void boo();
   struct func {
           std::string function_name; /* function name */
           void(*p)();   /* pointer to the function */
       };
       func my_func[1] = {
           { "boo", boo }
   };
   }
   ```

если объявлять функцию boo статичной, ошибка исчезает.

2. Как я поняла статические функции обращаются только к статическим функциям или можно каким то образом обойти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что пока ваша функция - член класса, она имеет не тип `void(*)()`, а вовсе даже `void(A::*)()`. А это совсем-совсем другая история.

Нестатической функции передается скрытый параметр - ссылка на объект, для которого она вызывается.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    ~A(){};

    void boo(){};

    struct func {
        std::string function_name; /* function name */
        void(A::*p)();   /* pointer to the function */
    };
    func my_func[1] = {
        { "boo",&A::boo }
    };
};
```

Как вызвать? ну, например, так:

```
A a, b;
(a.*b.my_func[0].p)();
```

Вызов функции-члена, внесенной в первый элемент массива `my_func` объекта `b`, для объекта `a`.

На очередной вопрос:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    ~A(){};

    void boo(){ cout << "boo\n"; };

    struct func {
        std::string function_name; /* function name */
        void(A::*p)();   /* pointer to the function */
    };
    func my_func[1] = {
        { "boo",&A::boo }
    };

    void zoo()
    {
        (this->*my_func[0].p)();
    }
};
```

Что еще прикажете написать? Или заодно приехать и полы помыть?...

Comment: @user:195342 как правильно обращаться? функция и указатель лежат в одном namespace и я думала что сначала проверяет в нет

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: где можно побольше об этом узнать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342

Comment: как вызвать функцию?      (*func[i].p) () куда тогда нужно вставить адрес и какой адрес?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ...

Comment: как вызвать из другой функции этого же класса? this->my_func[0].p() не работает

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.........