# r = rand() - код

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a , r;
r = rand();
for(a = 0;r<=20000;a++)
    r = rand();
    cout<<"R = " << r <<"A = " << a;
return 0;
}
```

Зачем мы пишем два раза r = rand(), нельзя просто написать r = rand() перед for или после for, разницы же нету? Если не написать r = rand() после for, то будет генерироваться случайное число, а если r = rand() не написать перед for, то программа вообще работать не будет. И почему генерируется одно и то же число? Можете дать пояснения всем функция и r = rand()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну смотрите -

```
r = rand();
for(a = 0;r<=20000;a++)
```

Если не вызывать первый `rand()`, то в `r` будет *мусор*, который вы и сравниваете с 20000. Что неверно - вам нужно сравнивать не мусор, а случайное значение, правда?...

Если так больше нравится -= перепишите код как

```
int a , r;
for(a = 0; (r = rand()) <= 20000; a++);
cout << "R = " << r << " A = " << a << endl;
```

Это просто метод определения, каким по счету будет сгенерировано случайное число, превышающее 20000. Если использовать ваш код - я бы переписал его с правильными отступами, чтобы это стало понятнее:

```
r = rand();
for(a = 0; r <= 20000; a++) r = rand();

cout << "R = " << r << "  A = " << a;
```

Одно и то же число - потому что генератор случайных чисел выдает при запуске одну и ту же последовательность, что полезно при отладке. Но вы можете избавиться от этого, дописав первой инструкцией после `int main() {`, например,

```
srand(time(0));
```

А вообще-то в С++ уже давно пора переходить на более современные средства из `<random>`, все ж таки уже 10 лет как стандарт С++11 принят...

Comment: Я учусь по книжке Герберт Шилдта,хорошая книжка,но старенькая.Но основа,есть основа.Спасибо вам за развернутый ответ,я все понял.Можно еще задать вам вопрос,по какой книжке вы учились?Может быть после Герберт Шилдта,купить книгу,по которой вы учились

Comment: Гм, когда я учился, Шилдт еще свои книги не писал :) Просто посмотрите сюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/195342

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас посмотрю!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вообще более логично было бы проинициализировать `r` нулём вместо `rand()` и в инициализаторе цикла:

```
int a, r;
for(a = 0, r = 0; r <= 20000; a++)
    r = rand();
```

Принцип `DRY` придумали не просто так, он по многим причинам полезен, код без повторений вызывает гораздо меньше вопросов.

И в таком варианте переменная `a` содержит в итоге ровно число вызовов `rand`. Если нужно, чтобы там было строго число вызовов `rand` **ДО** того, как выпало число больше `20000`, то можно потом вычесть `1` или инициализировать `a` в цикле `-1`, а не `0`