# Что я делаю не так? Помогите, я новичок

Tags: c++

Уже 4 часа сижу, а компилятор все ругается на "несуществующие переменные", которые есть.
Вот код:

````
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void startUp();

void spwnVars();

void cmdCheck();

void startUp()
{
    bool isCmdVarMade = false;
    string command;
    string echo;
    cout << "#############" << endl;
    cout << "##  C++OS  ##" << endl;
    cout << "#############" << endl;
    cout << "root@cppos# ";
}

int main()
{
    startUp();
    cmdCheck();
}

void spwnVars()
{
    if (isCmdVarMade == false)
    {
        cin >> command;
        isCmdVarMade == true;
    }
}

void cmdCheck()
{
    if (isCmdVarMade == false)
    {
        spwnVars();
    }

    if (command == "echo")
    {
        cout << "Input text to display." << endl;
        cout << "Input: ";
        cin >> echo;
        cout << echo << endl;
        cout << "root@cppos# ";
        command = "0";
        cin >> command;
        cmdCheck();
    }
    else if (command == "shutdown")
    {
        // finish
    }
}```
````

Comment: вы знаете что такое **область видимости**?

Comment: Знаете, поскольку понять, что вы хотите, не получается (в частности, это — `isCmdVarMade == true`), то вы просто перенесите строчки `bool isCmdVarMade = false;
    string command;
    string echo;` сразу после `using namespace std;`. Скомпилируется.

Comment: Возможно Вам будет полезно: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные то есть, но они локальные для функций, где Вы их объявляете. В таком случае, другие функции не будут видеть их.

**Однако, переменную можно объявить вначале программы, до функций, и она будет глобальной.**
Например:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isCmdVarMade = false;
```

**Или же можно нужным функциям передавать переменные по ссылкам.**
Например:

```
// создание такой функции
void spwnVars(int &isCmdVarMade, int &command)
{
    if (isCmdVarMade == false)
    {
        cin >> command;
        isCmdVarMade == true;
    }
}

// вызов
spwnVars(isCmdVarMade, command);
```

А вообще советую почитать, про локальные и глобальные переменные)
[-> Вот](https://cppstudio.com/post/415/)